# how do I find out if the cursor is in the bounds of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a drag and drop application and what I want to do is while the user is dragging an element get if the cursor is over certain other element.

Heres the flow:

User starts dragging an element around the page
When the mouse gets over certain parts I want to make an ajax call.

Because I know the elements and their bounds via jquery I just want the best way to make the check.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Start here: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

Get the mouse coordinates and compare it to the `.offset()` values of the item you're comparing it to.

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: Thats what I'm doing, but i was wondering if there is a better/easier way to do it

Comment: Generally it's safe to use events, but since you're bringing an item with you that's overlapping, the answer is: probably not. :(

Comment: Maybe hijack some of the code from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598953/find-elements-that-are-stacked-under-visually-an-element-in-jquery/5599301#5599301 It might be of value.

Answer (score 3):

The snippet mentioned by

https://stackoverflow.com/users/650094/adam-terlson

from

[find elements that are stacked under (visually) an element in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598953/find-elements-that-are-stacked-under-visually-an-element-in-jquery/5599301#5599301)

looks like this:

```
function mouseWithin(bounds,x,y) {
    var offset = bounds.offset();
    var l = offset.left;
    var t = offset.top;
    var h = bounds.height();
    var w = bounds.width();

    var maxx = l + w;
    var maxy = t + h;

    return (y <= maxy && y >= t) && (x <= maxx && x >= l);
};
```

you can use it like this:

```
var gallery=$("#carousel-gallery");
mouseWithin(gallery,event.pageX,event.pageY);
```

Answer (score 0):

$("#element").hover();

[Hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: or mouseenter() and mouseleave()

Comment: That doesn't work because I have an element attached to the mouse due to the dragging.