# elevate-zoom in jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

I am trying to use the elevate-zoom plugin in jquery tabs. It works fine in the first tab, but breaks when changing tabs. I understand what is happening, but don't know how to solve it. If I change the class it takes a second click for the .hide to take effect. I'm a rookie to jquery, any help would be appreciated. This is the first time I've posted code, I hope it's correct.

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.elevatezoom.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .hide { position: absolute; top: -9999px; left: -9999px; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper" style="min-height: 520px;">
    <div id="tabs" style="margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px; min-height: 460px; font-size: 9pt;">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span><b>First Panel</b></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Second Panel</span></a></li>
        </ul>

            <div id="fragment-1" class="first">
                <div id='Div1' style='margin-left: 60px;'>
                    <img id="zoom_01" src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Austin_Healey_3000_red_vl.jpg/800px-Austin_Healey_3000_red_vl.jpg' width="300" data-zoom-image="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Austin_Healey_3000_red_vl.jpg/800px-Austin_Healey_3000_red_vl.jpg"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="fragment-2">
                <div id='Div2' style='margin-left: 60px;'>
                    <img id="no_zoom" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/29/Austin-Healey_3000_at_2010_Ottawa_British_Auto_Show.jpg/800px-Austin-Healey_3000_at_2010_Ottawa_British_Auto_Show.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#tabs").tabs({ show: { effect: "blind", duration: 500} });

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion({ active: 0 });
        $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom({
            zoomWindowWidth: 300,
            zoomWindowHeight: 300,
            scrollZoom: true,
            easing: true,
            zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
            zoomWindowFadeOut: 500,
            lensFadeIn: 500,
            lensFadeOut: 500,
            zoomWindowPosition: 1,
            zoomWindowOffetx: 10
        });
    });


    $('#tabs').click('tabsselect', function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active') > 0)
            $(".first").addClass("hide")
        else
            $(".first").removeClass("hide")
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify the question. What is the desired behavior? What do you want to take place on tab / fragment 1? What do you want to take place on tab /fragment 2?  What does *breaks when I change tabs* mean?  Be very specific.

Comment: I want the zoom function to work on #fragment-1 only. Additional #fragments would have static content. When the page loads the zoom works properly, however when you select #fragment-2 and mouse over the crosshair and the zoom image appear over the content. At that point the tabs ui 'breaks' too and no longer works. Sorry for the lack of specificity.

Comment: So, do you want to *unbind* the elevateZoom from the image when the user clicks on a different tab? And then *rebind* when / if they click the first tab again?

Answer (score 1):

Simply bind the elevatZoom function to multiple elements, and you should be good to go:

```
$("#zoom_01, #zoom_02").elevateZoom({
        zoomWindowWidth: 300,
        zoomWindowHeight: 300,
        scrollZoom: true,
        easing: true,
        zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
        zoomWindowFadeOut: 500,
        lensFadeIn: 500,
        lensFadeOut: 500,
        zoomWindowPosition: 1,
        zoomWindowOffetx: 10
    });
```

Better yet, give your images a *class* of zoom (or similar), and you can change your selector to be easier to work with:

```
$(".zoom").elevateZoom({
```

Comment: That gives the same results. Perhaps I wasn't clear. I only want the elevate-zoom to operate on panel (0).

Comment: Edited #zoom_02 to #no_zoom.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the best solution I could find to the above problem, seems to work well:

```
    $('#tabs').click('tabsselect', function (event, ui) {
    if ($("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active') > 0) {
        $('.zoomContainer').remove();
    } else {
        $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom({
            zoomWindowWidth: 300,
            zoomWindowHeight: 300,
            scrollZoom: true,
            easing: true,
            zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
            zoomWindowFadeOut: 500,
            lensFadeIn: 500,
            lensFadeOut: 500,
            zoomWindowPosition: 1,
            zoomWindowOffetx: 10
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks to [mark-s](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1961198/mark-s) for his answer found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490554/bind-a-jquery-image-zoom-effect-to-onclick).