# Magnify effect only appears on mouse move

Tags: jquery, zooming

I am using this elevate zoom plugin on my site: http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom

I modified it slightly so that I can 'un-zoom' on a second click (as per this question: [Bind a jquery image zoom effect to onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490554/bind-a-jquery-image-zoom-effect-to-onclick))

Everything is working great, my only issue is that when you click to zoom the zoom effect only appears on mouse move. If you keep the mouse still nothing happens. This can be confusing for users. Try it out here:

http://www.fiercelycurious.com/collections/jake-wallace/products/big-allis

Any thoughts on how to make this effect appear only on click, not on click+move?

Thanks

Comment: Try to manually trigger a mousemove event after the click event. $(".zoom-container").trigger("mousemove")

Comment: Hmm - tried adding that after the addClass("zoomed") and it didn't work. Or I didn't do it right....