# How do I determine what elements are under a fixed div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-position

I have a object with position:fixed that I'm moving around a page in response to certain input from the user.  I'd like to be able to select the dom element under that div using javascript/jquery.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: By 'under'...do you mean contained by the div, or physically under as in a greater Y coordinate with the same X coordinate?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598953/find-elements-that-are-stacked-under-visually-an-element-in-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By 'under' I am assuming you mean the DOM object that is visually under (covered) by your `position:fixed` div.  In that case, you might find this answer useful:

[Using jQuery to find an element at a particular position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942776/jquery-find-element-at-a-particular-position)