# PHP, Jquery, JS. 2 buttons on each other, how to click them by 1 mouse click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

Possible to make, that by one mouse click 2 buttons will be clicked? I mean if buttons If are on each other.

[image]

I've tried to hide (set opaticy to 0) one of them, but only one is clicked which one is in front.

Maybe could I use `pointer-events`, but I don't know how to make It successfully? Or It impossible at all?

I've tried `pointer-events: none;`, but It disabled one button at all. So could you help me, please? Thank you.

Comment: are you trying to do this without any javascript at all?

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have two buttons like:

```
<input type="submit" name="savebutton" class="first button" />
<input type="submit" name="savebutton" class="second button" />
```

Now you just need to create a jquery function to trigger second button on the click of first button:

```
jQuery("input.first").click(function(){
   // trigger second button by javascript
    $(".second").click();
   return false;
});
```

Comment: @NitinJ Thank you for answer, but jQuery doesn't work for me, I don't know why. I've tried copy/paste this http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/WTzKR/ and this http://jsfiddle.net/wpELC/2/ to my blank page PHP page, but It not alert anything.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call event function on different element it's much easier to use separate functions:

```
var clickFunction1 = function(e) {
   // e.target will have targeted element if you need it
   // some code
   clickFunction2(e);
}

var clickFunction2 = function(e) {
   // some code
   clickFunction1(e);
}

$('#button-1').click(clickFunction1);
$('#button-2').click(clickFunction2);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g9K6N/

Also if I'm not mistaken if user performs event you can call `click` event yourself too

```
$('#button-1').click(function() {
    $('#button-2').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call click of second by javascript

```
$("#first button id").click(function(){
 $("#second button id").click();
})
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but jQuery doesn't work for me, I don't know why. I've tried copy/paste this http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/WTzKR/ and this http://jsfiddle.net/wpELC/2/ to my blank page PHP page, but It not alert anything.

Comment: have you include jquery.js in the head

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetAllElementsAt(x, y) {
    var $elements = $("body *").map(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var offset = $this.offset();
        var l = offset.left;
        var t = offset.top;
        var h = $this.height();
        var w = $this.width();

        var maxx = l + w;
        var maxy = t + h;

        return (y <= maxy && y >= t) && (x <= maxx && x >= l) ? $this : null;
    });

    return $elements;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598953/find-elements-that-are-stacked-under-visually-an-element-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

just Copy And Paste this code...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#my-group :button").click(function(){
    alert('testing...');
  });
});
</script>
<div id="my-group">
    <input type="button" name="Finish" value="Finish">
    <input type="button" name="Update" value="Update">
    <input type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel">
</div>

<div id="not-my-group">
    <input type="button" name="Finish" value="Finish">
    <input type="button" name="Update" value="Update">
    <input type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel">
</div>
```