# Allow selecting through div, but still track mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to write a JavaScript tool to let my users compare ranges of characters in slightly varied text strings. It's critical that the users still be able to select that text.

```
# || is a section my tool highlights. The number of characters the highlight covers starts at one, but can be varied by text selection. 

Foo |Bar Baz Quux|
Foo |Bra Biz Quix|
```

At present, a div contains a table. A secondary div is inside the first, and a third div is inside the second.

The second div overlies the text in the table, while the third is the div that actually appears semi-opaque over the text that the user wants to examine.

```
<div>
    <div class="text-cell-area">
        <div class="highlighter"></div>
    </div>
    <table>
        <tr><td>text</td></tr>
        <tr><td>text</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

On page load, I use JavaScript to modify `.text-cell-area` such that its offsets and dimensions completely cover all the text whose alignment I need to check; it's basically a box floating over several table rows.

Mouseover events and window.onmousemove track the user's cursor, setting the location of `.highlighter` to match the location of the user's cursor and snap to each monospaced character.

This functionality is fine - Alignment checking works perfectly. The problem is that I now have two divs overlying the text in my table so that I can't select it. I can't use `pointer-events: none;` to allow my users to the select the text because that prevents the mouseover event from tracking the user's cursor to set the location of the highlighting div.

What I need is a different way to allow my users to select the text underneath both divs. How might I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [find elements that are stacked under (visually) an element in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598953/find-elements-that-are-stacked-under-visually-an-element-in-jquery)

Comment: That answer may be similar to what I need, but I have to take it a step further and find how to send the underlying TDs my click event so that they know the user is selecting text.

Comment: I took a similar approach to that in the linked question and can now send `mousedown` and `mouseup` events to the `td`s underneath my secondary `div`s. The problem is that these events don't trigger any selection at all. I need to know how to invoke selection that corresponds to the where the user starts and ends their click on the `td`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by wrapping my `td` contents in `span`s with a labeling class, then adding `position:relative` and `z-index:50` to my `span` CSS attributes ([position attributes must be included for z-index to take effect](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)). I added `z-index`es lower than that of the spans to my highlighting-related `div`s. This allowed my users to select the text in the spans.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.onresize = function() {
    $(".text-area").css({
      left: $(".alignment-text").first().offset().left,
      top: $(".alignment-text").first().offset().top,
      width: (function() {
        var widest = 0;
        $(".alignment-text").each(function(index, element) {
          if($(element).width() > widest) widest = $(element).width();
        });
        return widest;
      })(),
      height: (function() {
        return ($(".alignment-text").last().offset().top + $(".alignment-text").last().height()) - $(".alignment-text").first().offset().top
      })()
    });
  };
                        
  $(window).trigger("resize");
  
  $(".text-area").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".highlighter").css("opacity", ".5");
  });
  
  $(".text-area").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".highlighter").css("opacity", "0");
  });
  
  $(".alignment-text").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".text-area").trigger("mouseenter");
  });
  
  $(".alignment-text").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".text-area").trigger("mouseleave");
  });
  
  window.onmousemove = function(e) {
    $(".highlighter").css({
      left: function() {
        return e.pageX - $(".text-area").offset().left - $(".highlighter").width()/2
      }
    });
  };
});
```

```css
.alignment-text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.alignment-text, .highlighter-spacer {
  font-family: Fixed, monospace;
}

.highlighter-spacer {
  opacity: 0;
}

.highlighter {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 3;
}

.text-area {
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-area">
  <span class="highlighter">
    <span class="highlighter-spacer">A</span>
  </div>
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Row name</th>
    <th>Text we need to see aligned!</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First row!</td>
    <td class="alignment-text">This is some text. It should line up at some point with the text beneath it.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second row!</td>
    <td class="alignment-text">Here's some more text. I hope it lines up okay.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, it also blocked mouse events on the `div`s since they were now positioned beneath the text. To solve this, I set event handlers for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` on `.td-contents` to trigger their respective counterparts in the wrapper div `.text-cell-area`. Users can now both select text and see the alignment of the text between rows.