# Can I select an element using CSS only if it is visually below another element?

Tags: html, css

I have the following Layout:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        html{
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
            color: white;
        }
        .outer{
            /*Maybe something here?*/
        }

        .inner_1{
            background-color: aquamarine;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 400px; /*(For testing)*/
        }

        .inner_2{
            background-color: mediumaquamarine;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 400px; /*For testing*/
        }

        /*or Something like this?*/
        /*inner_1:below{
            background-color:red;
        }*/

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner_1">
        <p>This is inner_1. Some Content goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner_2">
        <p>This should be red if it is <b>below</b> inner_1</p>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Is there a pure CSS way to select the second `div` only if it is below the first `div`? (Which is the case when the viewport-size drops below 800-ish px)

I want to apply color (or any CSS attribute) to the second div only if its below the first div.

I know I could use media-queries to put one div below the other and aplly styles to it but I don't know how much content will be in the div's so thats not an option.

Any ideas? please let me know.

**EDIT** I'm talking about visual representation.

Comment: What do you mean by "below" in a visual structure or in DOM?

Comment: No, you cannot. This is exactly what media queries are for.

Comment: How would I query for a line-break? I don't know at what width the line-break will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Use the `+` selector in CSS

```
.inner_1 + .inner_2 p {
    border: solid red 1px;
}
```

[See this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1q5r7um1/1/)

> The element+element selector is used to select elements that is placed immediately after (not inside) the first specified element.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure the question is not about DOM structure, but about visual representation.

Comment: I am indeed talking about visual representation.

Comment: @ClaasM. Then no, you can't do this without media queries.

Comment: How would I query for something like this if I don't know he width of the two div's?

Comment: @ClaasM. Missed the part about the content. Javascript is definitely not an option?

Comment: I am now using javascript. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easily using :nth-child() selector

```
.outer div:nth-child(2){background:red !important;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        html{
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
            color: white;
        }
        .outer{
            /*Maybe something here?*/
        }

        .inner_1{
            background-color: aquamarine;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 400px; /*(For testing)*/
        }

        .inner_2{
            background-color: mediumaquamarine;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 400px; /*For testing*/
        }

        /*or Something like this?*/
        .outer div:nth-child(2){background:red;}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner_1">
        <p>This is inner_1. Some Content goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner_2">
        <p>This should be red if it is <b>below</b> inner_1</p>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not talking about DOM, I'm talking about visual representation. (So I'd have to detect if there was a line-break between the two inner div's)

Answer (score 0):

I am now using javascript.
Complete solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598953/find-elements-that-are-stacked-under-visually-an-element-in-jquery)

```
function GetAllElementsAt(x, y) {
    var $elements = $("body *").map(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var offset = $this.offset();
        var l = offset.left;
        var t = offset.top;
        var h = $this.height();
        var w = $this.width();

        var maxx = l + w;
        var maxy = t + h;

        return (y <= maxy && y >= t) && (x <= maxx && x >= l) ? $this : null;
    });

    return $elements;
}
```