# Get Data behind a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have placed a moveable DIV over web page. I want to get data like text or image or HTML behind that div. Once I move it to a place on webpage and then press button. It should get that data behind that div and save in JavaScript variable.

I have attached image of what I have done so far. I need your suggestion how I can accomplish this task.

Screenshot of div over webpage:

[image: screenshot of div over webpage]

I used, interactJS library to create drag-able div.

Comment: Please show some code for me

Comment: maybe this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598953/find-elements-that-are-stacked-under-visually-an-element-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery and its `.next()` method, for example: `nextItemText = $("#your-div-id").next().text();`