# Is there a way to see if element is visible, clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any method or JavaScript library that can see if an element is *really* fully visible? As an example, suppose you need some UI button shown between certain elements and not take up more space on the page, as on this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/akyh7e5f/

html:

```
<div style="width:50%; display:inline-block">
<div class="a">
<div>
Some content here.
</div>
<div class="inserter">
insertme
</div>
</div>
<div class="b">
 <div>
 some other content
 </div>
</div>
</div>

<div style="width:49%; display:inline-block">
<div class="a" style="z-index:1">
<div>
Some content here.
</div>
<div class="inserter">
insertme
</div>
</div>
<div class="b" style="z-index:2">
 <div>
 some other content
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.a {
  height:80%;
  background: blue;
  position:relative;
}
.b {
  padding:30px;
  background:green;
  position:relative;
}

.inserter {
  position:absolute; z-index:9999;
  left:50%; margin-left:-20px;
  background: red;
}
```

In one case the element is inside and shows, in the other case it is under because some other element has more zindex than a container of the insertme element. I could make it body > element direct child, but then EVERY change to the height of the element would required a change to the position.

You could move the red element up one dom element until it is after the element and visible, then do some calculations for top/left,

**or**, perhaps more performant, change it from absolute to relative and make it take up space, in the second case it will not show (which is not as great from a design perspective).

In either of these two cases, I need to know whether the element (red element in this fiddle) *is actually visible and clickable with no element above it. Is there any library that can find this?*

Please do not reply with a specific suggestion for the jsfiddle - this is a minimal test case, assume many different styles may theme the page in any way, not to mention user-added styles. Also please do not mention Selenium as this has to be a browser-only dynamic app.

Comment: @guradio You clearly haven't read the question.

Comment: I see an example that might help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598953/find-elements-that-are-stacked-under-visually-an-element-in-jquery ...could be a slow way to do it. Hope this helps.

Comment: @LeonBambrick is pretty closer to the question, also you might find this helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230029/jquery-javascript-collision-detection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can use [`elementFromPoint()`](https://jsfiddle.net/akyh7e5f/1/) to test if the element you want is the top element at it's offset coordinates.

This is not a full test for your issue but should help give you part of it

```
$('.inserter').each(function(){
   var offset= $(this).offset();
   var topEl = document.elementFromPoint(offset.left, offset.top);
   console.log(topEl == this)

})
```

Note I only checked the top left corner, you would probably want to see if more of it is displayed than just that corner.

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/akyh7e5f/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

For puppeteer I needed this and used @charlietfl answer to do it but with  more checks

```
    await page.waitForFunction(
      (browserSelector) => {
        const browserElement = document.querySelector(browserSelector);
        if (!browserElement) {
          console.log(`Cannot find element "${browserSelector}"`); // eslint-disable-line no-console
          return false;
        }

        const boundingBox = browserElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (boundingBox.width === 0) {
          console.log(`Element "${browserSelector}" has no width`); // eslint-disable-line no-console
          return false;
        }
        if (boundingBox.height === 0) {
          console.log(`Element "${browserSelector}" has no height`); // eslint-disable-line no-console
          return false;
        }

        const clickTarget = document.elementFromPoint(
          boundingBox.left + boundingBox.width / 2, // Horizontal center
          boundingBox.top + boundingBox.height / 2, // Vertical center
        );
        if (!browserElement.contains(clickTarget)) {
          console.log(`Element "${browserSelector}" is obstructed`); // eslint-disable-line no-console
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      },
      {}, // No options for waitForFunction
      selector,
    );
```