# Stacking different HTML elements; which goes above which?

Tags: html, css

I've made a smiley at the following link: http://jsfiddle.net/UzvWc/4/.

Unfortunately, when I embed the smiley within a complex page, with many different HTML elements, not every part of the smiley appears, some are hidden by other elements.

How can I have my smiley stack over **all other** elements?

Comment: That would depend on the element's css that surround it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. Which elements is it hidden by?

Anyways, here's one "catch-all" way: set

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999;
```

on the smiley. It should work.

Comment: With the caveat that this will work as long as there is no z-index higher than that. Here's a question regarding finding the highest z -index on your doc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118198/how-can-you-figure-out-the-highest-z-index-in-your-document

Comment: @citizen conn: 10,000 absolutely-positioned elements on a page with no positioned container is fairly rare, isn't it? It's not like other cases...

Comment: yeah totally, but he should know it anyway. There are plugins for finding the highest z index and it would be best to use that.