# parseInt vs unary plus, when to use which?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What are the differences between this line:

```js
var a = parseInt("1", 10); // a === 1
```

and this line

```js
var a = +"1"; // a === 1
```

This [jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/parseint-vs-unary-operator) shows that the unary operator is much faster in the current chrome version, assuming it is for node.js!?

If I try to convert strings which are not numbers both return `NaN`:

```js
var b = parseInt("test", 10); // b === NaN
var b = +"test"; // b === NaN
```

So when should I prefer using `parseInt` over the unary plus (especially in node.js)???

**edit**: and what's the difference to the double tilde operator `~~`?

Comment: Benchmark http://jsperf.com/parseint-vs-unary-operator

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The service seems dead. Any update?

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Well, here are a few differences I know of:

- An empty string `""` evaluates to a `0`, while `parseInt` evaluates it to `NaN`. IMO, a blank string should be a `NaN`.

  ```
    +'' === 0;              //true
    isNaN(parseInt('',10)); //true
  ```
- The unary `+` acts more like `parseFloat` since it also accepts decimals.

  `parseInt` on the other hand stops parsing when it sees a non-numerical character, like the period that is intended to be a decimal point `.`.

  ```
    +'2.3' === 2.3;           //true
    parseInt('2.3',10) === 2; //true
  ```
- `parseInt` and `parseFloat` parses and builds the string *left to right*. If they see an invalid character, it returns what has been parsed (if any) as a number, and `NaN` if none was parsed as a number.

  The unary `+` on the other hand will return `NaN` if the entire string is non-convertible to a number.

  ```
    parseInt('2a',10) === 2; //true
    parseFloat('2a') === 2;  //true
    isNaN(+'2a');            //true
  ```
- As seen in the comment of [@Alex K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246342), `parseInt` and `parseFloat` will parse by character. This means hex and exponent notations will fail since the `x` and `e` are treated as non-numerical components (at least on base10).

  The unary `+` will convert them properly though.

  ```
    parseInt('2e3',10) === 2;  //true. This is supposed to be 2000
    +'2e3' === 2000;           //true. This one's correct.

    parseInt("0xf", 10) === 0; //true. This is supposed to be 15
    +'0xf' === 15;             //true. This one's correct.
  ```

Comment: Also when using a radix `+"0xf" != parseInt("0xf", 10)`

Comment: i like your answer most so far, can you also explain what the difference to the double tilde operator ~~ is?

Comment: @hereandnow78 That would be [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4055633/575527). It's bitwise equivalent of `Math.floor()`, which basically chops off the decimal part.

Comment: If you plan to use different radices then `parseInt("0xf")` would yield 15, too.

Comment: Actually, `"2e3"` is not a valid integer representation for `2000`. It is a valid floating point number though: `parseFloat("2e3")` will correctly yield `2000` as the answer. And `"0xf"` requires at least base 16, which is why `parseInt("0xf", 10)` returns `0`, whereas `parseInt("0xf", 16)` returns the value of 15 you were expecting.

Comment: @Joseph the Dreamer and @hereandnow78: Double tilde cuts off the decimal part of the number, while Math.floor returns the closest lower number. They work the same for positive number, but `Math.floor(-3.5) == -4` and `~~-3.5 == -3`.

Answer (score 412):

The ultimate whatever-to-number conversion table:
[image: Conversion table]

```js
EXPRS = [
    'parseInt(x)',
    'parseFloat(x)',
    'Number(x)',
    '+x',
    '~~x',
    'x>>>0',
    'isNaN(x)'

];

VALUES = [
    '"123"',
    '"+123"',
    '"-123"',
    '"123.45"',
    '"-123.45"',
    '"12e5"',
    '"12e-5"',
    
    '"0123"',
    '"0000123"',
    '"0b111"',
    '"0o10"',
    '"0xBABE"',
    
    '"4294967295"',
    '"123456789012345678"',
    '"12e999"',

    '""',
    '"123foo"',
    '"123.45foo"',
    '"  123   "',
    '"foo"',
    '"12e"',
    '"0b567"',
    '"0o999"',
    '"0xFUZZ"',

    '"+0"',
    '"-0"',
    '"Infinity"',
    '"+Infinity"',
    '"-Infinity"',
    'BigInt(1)',

    'null',
    'undefined',
    'true',
    'false',
    'Infinity',
    'NaN',

    '{}',
    '{valueOf: function(){return 42}}',
    '{toString: function(){return "56"}}',

];

//////

function wrap(tag, s) {
    if (s && s.join)
        s = s.join('');
    return '<' + tag + '>' + String(s) + '</' + tag + '>';
}

function table(head, rows) {
    return wrap('table', [
        wrap('thead', tr(head)),
        wrap('tbody', rows.map(tr))
    ]);
}

function tr(row) {
    return wrap('tr', row.map(function (s) {
        return wrap('td', s)
    }));
}

function val(n) {
    return n === true || Number.isNaN(n) || n === "Error" ? wrap('b', n) : String(n);
}

var rows = VALUES.map(function (v) {
    var x = eval('(' + v + ')');
    return [v].concat(EXPRS.map(function (e) {
        try {
            return val(eval(e));
        } catch {
            return val("Error");
        }
    }));
});

document.body.innerHTML = table(["x"].concat(EXPRS), rows);
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse }
tr:nth-child(odd) { background: #fafafa }
td { border: 1px solid #e0e0e0; padding: 5px; font: 12px monospace }
td:not(:first-child) { text-align: right }
thead td { background: #3663AE; color: white }
b { color: red }
```

Comment: Please add `"NaN"` to this table.

Comment: It might be worth adding an `isNaN` column to this table: for example, `isNaN("")` is false (i.e it's considered a number), but `parseFloat("")` is `NaN`, which can be a gotcha, if you're trying to use `isNaN` to validate the input before passing it to `parseFloat`

Comment: You should also add `'{valueOf: function(){return 42}, toString: function(){return "56"}}'` to the list. The mixed results are interesting.

Comment: So, the summary of the table is that `+` is just a shorter way of writing `Number`, and the furter ones are just crazy ways to do it that fail on edge cases?

Comment: Is [].undef a thing, or is that just an arbitrary way of generating undefined?  Can't find any record of "undef" related to JS through Google.

Comment: @jcairney: yes, just a way to generate an undefined

Comment: `console.log(isNaN('0o10')); // true in IE`. And IE does not support `Number.isNaN()`. Use `isNaN()` instead. The table in picture is not true by different browsers.

Comment: Reason I will never use parseInt: `parseInt("1abcde344543*&$$#!$") // 1`

Answer (score 12):

The table in thg435's answer I believe is comprehensive, however we can summarize with the following patterns:

- Unary plus does not treat all falsy values the same, but they all come out falsy.
- Unary plus sends `true` to 1, but `"true"` to `NaN`.
- On the other hand, `parseInt` is more liberal for strings that are not pure digits.  `parseInt('123abc') === 123`, whereas `+` reports `NaN`.
- `Number` will accept valid decimal numbers, whereas `parseInt` merely drops everything past the decimal. Thus `parseInt` mimics C behavior, but is perhaps not ideal for evaluating user input.
- Both trim whitespace in strings.
- `parseInt`, being a badly designed *parser*, accepts octal and hexadecimal input. Unary plus only takes hexademical.

Falsy values convert to `Number` following what would make sense in C:  `null` and `false` are both zero.  `""` going to 0 doesn't quite follow this convention but makes enough sense to me.

Therefore I think if you are validating user input, unary plus has correct behavior for everything except it accepts decimals (but in my real life cases I'm more interested in catching email input instead of userId, value omitted entirely, etc.), whereas parseInt is too liberal.

Comment: "Unary plus only takes hexadecimal" Don't you mean decimal?

Answer (score 1):

Be carefull, parseInt is faster than + unary operator in Node.JS,
it's false that + or |0 are faster, them are faster only for NaN elements.

Check this out:

```
var arg=process.argv[2];

rpt=20000;
mrc=1000;

a=[];
b=1024*1024*1024*1024;
for (var i=0;i<rpt;i++)
 a[i]=Math.floor(Math.random()*b)+' ';

t0=Date.now();
if ((arg==1)||(arg===undefined))
 for (var j=0;j<mrc;j++) for (var i=0;i<rpt;i++) {
  c=a[i]-0;
 }
t1=Date.now();
if ((arg==2)||(arg===undefined)) {
 for (var j=0;j<mrc;j++) for (var i=0;i<rpt;i++) {
  d=a[i]|0;
 }
}
t2=Date.now();
if ((arg==3)||(arg===undefined)) {
 for (var j=0;j<mrc;j++) for (var i=0;i<rpt;i++) {
  e=parseInt(a[i]);
 }
}
t3=Date.now();
 if ((arg==3)||(arg===undefined)) {
 for (var j=0;j<mrc;j++) for (var i=0;i<rpt;i++) {
  f=+a[i];
 }
}
t4=Date.now();

console.log(a[i-1],c,d,e,f);
console.log('Eseguiti: '+rpt*mrc+' cicli');
console.log('parseInt '+(t3-t2));
console.log('|0 '+(t2-t1));
console.log('-0 '+(t1-t0));
console.log('+ '+(t4-t3));
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend use Math.floor (or ~~ if you know numbers are positive) instead of parseString. +(expression) is out of scope, because +(expression) is more like parseFloat. Look this little benchmark:

```sh
// 1000000 iterations each one
node test_speed
Testing ~~, time: 5 ms
Testing parseInt with number, time: 25 ms
Testing parseInt with string, time: 386 ms
Testing Math.floor, time: 18 ms
```

The source code of benchmark:

```js
/* el propósito de este script es evaluar
que expresiones se ejecutan más rápido para así 
decidir cuál usar */

main()
async function main(){
    let time, x 
    let number = 23456.23457
    
    let test1 = ()=>{
        x = 0
        time = Date.now() 
        for(let i=0;i<1000000;i++){
            let op = Math.floor(number / 3600)
            x = op
        }
        console.info("Testing Math.floor, time:", Date.now() - time, "ms")
    }

    let test2 = ()=>{
        x = 0
        time = Date.now() 
        for(let i=0;i<1000000;i++){
            let op = parseInt(number / 3600)
            x = op
        }
        console.info("Testing parseInt with number, time:", Date.now() - time, "ms")
    }

    let test3 = ()=>{
        x = 0
        time = Date.now() 
        for(let i=0;i<1000000;i++){
            let op = parseInt((number / 3600).toString())
            x = op
        }
        console.info("Testing parseInt with string, time:", Date.now() - time, "ms")
    }

    let test4 = ()=>{
        x = 0
        time = Date.now() 
        for(let i=0;i<1000000;i++){
            let op = ~~(number / 3600)
            x = op
        }
        console.info("Testing ~~, time:", Date.now() - time, "ms")
    }
    
    test4()
    test2()
    test3()
    test1()
    
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Consider [performance](http://jsperf.com/parseint-vs-unary-operator) too. I was suprised that `parseInt` beats unary plus on iOS :) This is helpful for web apps with heavy CPU consumption only. As a rule-of-thumb I'd suggest JS opt-guys to consider any JS operator over another one from the mobile performance point of view nowadays.

So, go **mobile-first** ;)

Comment: As the other posts explain they do quite different things, so you can't easily swap one for the other…

Comment: @Bergi, right, but they also have a lot in common. Tell me just one performance solution in JavaScript that is definitely the only right choice? In general that's why rule-of-thumbs are out there for us. The rest is task-specific.

Comment: @ArmanMcHitaryan this is useless microoptimisation and it does not worth it. Check out this article - http://fabien.potencier.org/article/8/print-vs-echo-which-one-is-faster

Comment: @webvitaly, nice article. There are always very perf-oriented guys out there who just like to write "the fastest possible" code and in some specific projects that's not bad. That's why I mentioned "JS opt-guys to consider". this is not A MUST of course :), but I myself find it much more readable in addition.

Comment: Do you have a citation for this? Your link is broken.

Comment: I can tell you guys that micro-optimizations like this made my 3D biomedical imaging code run at acceptable performance, so I wouldn't dismiss this stuff out of hand. I also saw changing Math.trunc to ~~ make a procedurally generated canvas render run acceptably smooth so YMMV. The reason that these optimizations worked was that it was in a tight loop being called millions of times per a frame.