# javascript idioms for doing common things

Tags: javascript

I've been programming JS for a bunch of years and I am still finding new shortcuts for doing things.
I am wondering if there are more that I do not know about.

Here are the shortcuts I know about:

**edit**: I agree that you should generally never do this stuff, and  that there could be a better way to describe it as to be less broad, but the best I can do is describe it by example.

---

Instead of this

```
if("foobar".indexOf("foo") > -1)
```

Do this

```
if(~"foobar".indexOf("foo"))
```

---

Instead of this

```
var foo = Math.floor(2.333)
```

Do this

```
var foo = ~~2.333
```

---

Instead of this

```
var foo = parseFloat("12.4")
var bar = parseInt("12", 10)
```

Do this (not huge fan of this one )

```
var foo = +"12.4"
var bar = +"12"
```

---

Instead of this

```
if(isNaN(foo)
```

Do this

```
if(foo != foo)
```

---

Instead of this

```
(function(){ ... })()
```

Do this

```
!function(){ ... }()
```

---

Convert anything to a boolean by prefixing it with `!!`

```
var isFoo = !!foo
```

---

There you have it, my list of things to never do to your coworkers.

Can anything else be added here?

Comment: The only shortcuts that I would actually use are `!!` and `+"1"`. The rest have unintended side effects (`~~10000000000000 == 1316134912`, for example) or just look funny.

Comment: @mkoryak: I was talking more about the bitwise operations, which will convert your numbers to signed 32-bit integers.

Comment: @mkoryak, aside from being "too broad", you should use the "Answer Your Own Question" checkbox, or move the answer part to an answer.

Comment: its not too broad, unless you know of any more of these that i dont know about. I cant answer my own question because I think there are more of these that I don't know about, and people dont tend to answer questions that have an accepted answer, no?

Comment: More of what, exactly?  *Shortcut* is an incredibly vague term and you could give pretty much any answer as a shortcut for something else.

Comment: ok, help my come with with a better title. i have examples of what i am looking for right there in the question. More of those!

Comment: 'Idiom' might be a better word than 'shortcut'... it's often used to bowdlerize shitty coding practices in C and Perl :P

Comment: Idioms are generally good, shortcuts are generally bad.  Programmers like idioms, bosses like shortcuts (who cares how the code looks, anyway?  Clients don't see it!)

Comment: @mkoryak it is too broad. Read the source of [lodash](http://lodash.com/) for a zillion more.

Comment: [See my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17433873/pattern-for-treating-zero-as-truthy) (which I will note had mixed reactions) for a far more specific question regarding Javascript "shortcuts" that *still* had several answers. Your question is *far* broader.

Comment: `~~2.333` This's new to me, thanks!

Comment: As a 14k rep user, you should *really* know by now that this question is totally off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 15):

This question will probably get closed as being too broad, and this answer may garner its fair share of downvotes for not answering directly, but here goes.

*Please*, ***please***, be really circumspect about using "shortcuts" in a programming language, because... *really*... who are they helping?

Most of these shortcuts sacrifice clarity and explicitness for keystrokes. You won't find a single, competent, professional coder who will agree that that is a sensible trade off.

Consider

```
if("foobar".indexOf("foo") > -1)
```

to

```
if(~"foobar".indexOf("foo"))
```

You've saved 4 characters... whoopie! However, you've also guaranteed that anybody who doesn't know this shortcut has a very slim chance of being able to figure out what is going on here... and certainly not with ease.

Reading the definition of `indexOf` is enough to understand the explicit version. For the second one, you need to understand what `~` means (which is a fairly uncommon operator in JS). You then need to know what the bitwise complement of -1 is. You then need to realise that it is truthy.

It's a foolish tradeoff and it is a hallmark of many of these idioms.

*Please don't do it*. This isn't the 80s.

Comment: " This isn't the 80s." - oh poop, the drugs must have worn off. Dammit!  (+1 BTW)

Comment: I appreciate that the OP lists them as "Things to never do to your coworker" and applaude him for that.

Comment: +1. I would have written this in the question, but as you said, it will be closed, plus long questions are often skipped.

Answer (score 4):

- `n | 0` floors `n` (only if `n` is within the signed 32-bit integer range). It's faster than `Math.floor()` in most browsers last I checked.
- `undefined == null`, but neither are equal to `false`.
- Instead of `x == 'a' || x == 'b' || x == 'c'`, you can do `['a', 'b', 'c'].indexOf(x) !== -1`

The only truly short shortcut that I've seen in production code is the unary `+` to convert strings into numbers.

Comment: `n | 0` is the same as `Math.trunc` for the signed 32-bit integer range.  It is not the same as `Math.floor` for negative values.

Answer (score 3):

I see this one a lot:

```
myString = "Some string."
b = myString[myString.length - 1]; // get the period
```

Should be

```
b = myString.slice(-1);
```

---

The for while loop.

```
for (var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var x = a[i];
    console.log(x);
}
```

to

```
for (var i=0,x; (x=a[i++]) != null; ) {
    console.log(x);
}
```

---

Put this at the top of a script.

```
String.prototype.has = Array.prototype.has = function(a){ return this.indexOf(a) !== -1; }
```

Turns these

```
if (myString.indexOf(a) !== -1)
if (myArray.indexOf(a) !== -1)
```

to these

```
if (myString.has(a))
if (myArray.has(a))
```

---

For when you need to put 42 in your code, but sneakily.

```
var answer = ((((1<<2)|1)<<2)|1)<<1;
```

---

CoffeeScript

... need I say more?

Comment: Thanks, this is useful and very much on the topic of what i was asking for. Yes coffeescript rocks :)

Comment: Yeah, the question just reminded me of a lot of "So, which is your favorite" questions at first, and second glances :-)

Comment: This `for (var i=0,x; (x=a[i++]) != null; )` is brilliant. Thanks!

Comment: As with many shortcuts, that array one fails in unexpected ways. For `a=[1,2,,3,4,5]`, you only get the 1 and the 2. This is because `undefined == null` is `true`.