# Javascript testing for NaN

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, nan

The below block of code asks the server for an adjusted account balance after the user inputs a number to quantity, price and payment fields. Adding `--10` to a field would throw an error on the server. That's why I've added the NaN check `adjustment === adjustment`. This way it should only send the request if the adjustment amount is a number. For some reason though, I'm still getting strange things being sent to the server like `--10`...

Essentially, I need to only send the request when it is actually a number.

```
var quantity = $("#id_quantity").val();
    var price = $("#id_price").val();
    var payment = $("#id_payment_amount").val();
    var adjustment = quantity * price - payment;
    // Don't send if Not a number (NaN).
    if (adjustment === adjustment) {
        $.get("/balance_after_adjustment", {amount: adjustment}, function(response) {
            $("span").text(response);
        });
    }
```

Comment: `isNaN()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN , and `Number.isNaN()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN

Comment: You're getting the values as strings, then running a mathematical calculation on them. I'd suggest parsing each item individually using `parseFloat` or `parseInt`, that way you get good numbers first before trying to do any calculations on them.

Comment: Still, do not forget to test `amount` at server side. Otherwise some "hacker" may overcome Javascript check.

Comment: @JoeEnos I don't see how that would change anything. The operators will implicitly convert to numbers anyways. And I wouldn't use the `parse` functions on user input; the unary `+` operator or `Number()` function make more sense

Comment: @Ian It may not be the whole solution, but it would allow you to test one at a time each of the inputs, and report a failed parse on the specific field that was typed incorrectly. I didn't know about the unary `+` operator, looks like that would work well. Seems there are [a few differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106681/parseint-vs-unary-plus-when-to-use-which), but for a good number it appears like that might be the better solution.

Comment: @JoeEnos I definitely agree with this last comment of yours - you didn't mention testing each one and reporting back any failures, which I wasn't sure if it was something the OP wanted...nonetheless, a good suggestion. My other point was that the `parse` functions ignore any trailing non-digit characters, while the unary `+` operator and `Number()` (which do the same thing) do not. When dealing with user input, ignoring trailing characters may or may not be desired, but I wanted to point that out. I can't think of many/any scenarios where the `parse` functions should be used over `+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably try something like this

```
var quantity = parseInt($("#id_quantity").val(),10),
 price = parseInt($("#id_price").val(),10),
 payment = parseInt($("#id_payment_amount").val(),10),
 adjustment = quantity * price - payment;
if (!isNaN(adjustment)) {
    $.get("/balance_after_adjustment", {amount: adjustment}, function(response) {
        $("span").text(response);
    });
}
```

Comment: There is no isNaN() method like that.

Comment: Sorry typo fixed now though

Answer (score -1):

put a `+` before the statement so the string returned by the method `val` will be casted as integer

```
var quantity = +$("#id_quantity").val(),
    price = +$("#id_price").val(),
    payment = +$("#id_payment_amount").val();
```