# How to fix Uncaught InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to port my googlemaps v2 functions to v3.

But somehow i stuck in a strange error and i could not find, what i'm doing wrong.

> Error : Uncaught InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number   %7Bmain,adsense,geometry,zombie%7D.js:25

Here my map initialisation:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),{
  zoom:4
  size:new google.maps.Size(580,440),
  mapTypeControl: true,
  mapTypeControlOptions: {
    style:google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.VERTICAL_BAR,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER,
  },
  panControl: true,
  panControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT,
  },
  zoomControl: true,
  zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER,
  },
  scaleConrol: true,
  scaleControlOptions:{
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT ,
  },
});
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(49.477643, 9.316406));
```

and here the part with my error:

```
function drawTraders(map, options) {
var traders_uri = options.traders_uri || '';
if ('' == traders_uri) {
    return false;
}

// get the informations
$.getJSON(traders_uri, function(data) {
    // look through the information
$.each(data.traders, function(i, trader) {
var icon = options.icon_image_uri;

var markerIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon,
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
    new google.maps.Size(25, 25),
    // The origin for this image is 0,0.
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
    new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
);

var html = 'test';

/*Information from chromium debugger
trader: Object
    geo: Object
        lat: "49.014821"
        lon: "10.985072"

*/
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(trader.geo.lat,trader.geo.lon);

/*here is the error in new google.maps.Marker()*/
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:   myLatlng,
    map: map,
    icon : markerIcon,
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: html
});
}
```

Edit: the call of drawTraders

```
 drawTraders(map, {
        traders_uri: "getTraders.php",
        icon_image_uri: "icon-cms.gif",
 });
```

I was using this example [Info Window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple)

Edit:

[Fiddle which is not working](http://jsfiddle.net/BF3Yv/13/)

[Fiddle which works](http://jsfiddle.net/BF3Yv/14/)

Answer (score 122):

> Uncaught InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

Means you are not passing *numbers* into the google.maps.LatLng constructor.  Per your comment:

```
/*Information from chromium debugger
trader: Object
    geo: Object
        lat: "49.014821"
        lon: "10.985072"

*/
```

trader.geo.lat and trader.geo.lon are strings, not numbers. Use parseFloat to convert them to numbers:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(trader.geo.lat),parseFloat(trader.geo.lon));
```

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem with exactly the same error message. In the end the error was, that I still called the maps v2 javascript. I had to replace:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=####################" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=####################&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

after this, it worked fine. took me a while ;-)

Answer (score 6):

you can use this way

```
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 16,
        center: { lat: parseFloat(lat), lng: parseFloat(lng) },
        mapTypeId: 'terrain', 
        disableDefaultUI: true
 });
```

*EX :* center: { lat: **parseFloat(lat)**, lng: **parseFloat(lng)** },

Answer (score 4):

**I was having the same problem, the fact is that the input of lat and long should be String. Only then did I manage.**

for example:

Controller.

```
 ViewBag.Lat = object.Lat.ToString().Replace(",", ".");

 ViewBag.Lng = object.Lng.ToString().Replace(",", ".");
```

View - function javascript

```
<script>
    function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = { lat: @ViewBag.Lat, lng: @ViewBag.Lng};

        // Create a map object and specify the DOM element for display.
        var map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
        {
            center: myLatLng,
            scrollwheel: false,
            zoom: 16
        });

        // Create a marker and set its position.
        var marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: myLatLng
            //title: "Blue"
        });
    }
</script>
```

**I convert the double value to string and do a Replace in the ',' to '.' And so everything works normally.**

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when setting the center of the map with `map.setCenter()`. Using `Number()` solved for me. Had to use `parseFloat` to truncate the data.

**code snippet:**

```
 var centerLat = parseFloat(data.lat).toFixed(0);
 var centerLng = parseFloat(data.long).toFixed(0);
 map.setCenter({
      lat: Number(centerLat),
      lng: Number(centerLng)
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [angular-google-maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/)

```
$scope.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i = $scope.markers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    $scope.bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng($scope.markers[i].coords.latitude, $scope.markers[i].coords.longitude));
};    
$scope.control.getGMap().fitBounds($scope.bounds);
$scope.control.getGMap().setCenter($scope.bounds.getCenter());
```

Answer (score 3):

What about casting to Number in Javascript using the Unary (+) Operator

```
lat: 12.23
```

```
lat: +12.23
```

**Depends on the use case.** Here is a fullchart what works and what not:
 [parseInt vs unary plus - when to use which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106681/parseint-vs-unary-plus-when-to-use-which/17106702#17106702)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and resolved it.
In my case it was error due to the non-proper format. Please check the first and last coordinates array in geometry coordinates they must be same then and only then it will work. Hope it may help you!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably passing `null` value if you're loading the coordinates dynamically, set a check before you call the map loader ie: `if(mapCords){loadMap}`