# InvalidValueError: in property latLng: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object

Tags: php, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I have a directions service in my php page for which I take destination latlng value from another php page

```
var dest='<?php echo $dest;?>';
```

The directions do display. I want to show the address of destination from the latlng for which I had used reverse-geocoding:

```
var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geo.geocode({'latLng':dest},function(results,status){
document.getElementById('txtDestination').innerHTML = results[1].formatted_address;
});
```

But it is not taking the value of latlng throwing the error:

```
InvalidValueError: in property latLng: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object
```

I had test value of dest using `alert()` it shows correct but I don't why it doesnt take in `Geocoder()`

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585055/uncaught-invalidvalueerror-setposition-not-a-latlng-or-latlngliteral-in-prope

Comment: What is the value of `dest`?  Sounds like it isn't a LatLng or a LatLngLiteral.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: `dest` is the latlng value which i pass from anchor tag from another php file