# Get the maps marker to the LAT and LONG coordinates passed via the database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps

I am getting the location of the user automatically when a user check in to mark their attendance in the morning. I am sucessfully fetching the latitude and longitude coordinates and save them in the database for further usage.

From the admins panel i want the admin to see the location of the coordinates saved in the database table. For this function i have a table looking like below,

[image: UI Table With Attendance Records]

And since each of attendances recorded can have different coordinates i have placed a button with the Map marker icon. And when the admin clicks on one of the map marker icon a modal is popped up with the values of the coordinates (The lat and long)

This is how I have written the code for the table.

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" style="width: 100%; text-                    
align: center;">
<thead>
<tr>

<th><strong>Name</strong></th>
<th><strong>Date</strong></th>
<th><strong>Time</strong></th>
<th><strong>In / Out</strong></th>
<th ><strong></strong></th>
<th style="text-align: center; width:2%;"><strong></strong></th>

</tr>
</thead>
<br>
<tbody>
<?php
$query="SELECT employees.EMP_ID, employees.Name, attendance.* FROM employees INNER JOIN attendance ON 
employees.Email = attendance.Email_Address;";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
if($result->num_rows>0){
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
<tr>

<td style="text-align: center;">
<?php echo $row["Name"]; ?></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $row["Date_Log"]; ?></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $row["Time_Log"]; ?></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><?php if ($row['IN_OUT']=="In") {
  ?>
  <span class="badge bg-success"><?php echo $row["IN_OUT"]; ?></span>
  <?php
}
else if ($row['IN_OUT']=="Out"){
  ?>
  <span class="badge bg-danger"><?php echo $row["IN_OUT"]; ?></span>
  <?php
}
?>
</td>

<td><a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModaldaterange"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf" 
style="color: green;"></i></a></td>

<td style="text-align: center; width:2%;">
<?php
if ($row['Latitude']=="Location Not Fetched" && $row['Longitude']=="Location Not Fetched") {
  ?>
  <span class="badge bg-info text-dark">Location Not Fetched</span>
  <?php
}
else{
  ?>
  <a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModallocation"  latitude="<?php echo 
$row['Latitude']; ?>" longgitu="<?php echo $row['Longitude'];?>" role="button" class="btn btn- 
primary"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></a>
  <?php
}
?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } }
else {
  ?>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  Oops No Records Were Found For The Search Term - <?php echo $empidsearch; ?>
  </div>
  <?php
} ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Note this code

```
<td style="text-align: center; width:2%;">
<?php
if ($row['Latitude']=="Location Not Fetched" && $row['Longitude']=="Location Not Fetched") {
?>
<span class="badge bg-info text-dark">Location Not Fetched</span>
<?php
}
else{
?>
<a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModallocation"  latitude="<?php echo 
$row['Latitude']; ?>" longgitu="<?php echo $row['Longitude'];?>" role="button" class="btn btn- 
primary"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></a>
<?php
}
?>
</td>
```

I have set the lat and long values fetched from the database to the button and when on the button is cliked a modal is opened where i have 2 inputs, and on the two inputs these two lat and long coordinates are shown successfully like shown below,

[image: Modal Of Map]

And the JS code for getting the lat and long from the table to the modal is as follows,

```
var lat1;
var long1;
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#exampleModallocation').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
// get information to update quickly to modal view as loading begins
var opener=e.relatedTarget;//this holds the element who called the modal 
//we get details from attributes
lat1=$(opener).attr('latitude');
long1=$(opener).attr('longgitu');
//set what we got to our form
$('#profileForm').find('[name="latitude"]').val(parseFloat(lat1));
$('#profileForm').find('[name="longgitu"]').val(parseFloat(long1));
console.log(lat1);
initMap(lat1, long1);
```

});

});

And now i have tried to attach this lat and long values to the map coordinates but i am unable to do so since there are errors thrown.

The code written for the Javascript Maps Api (Google) are as follow,

```
function initMap(lat1, long1) {
const myLatLng = { lat: lat1, lng: long1 };
const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
zoom: 4,
center: { lat: 6.927079, lng: 79.861244 },
});
const image =
"https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png";
const beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: { lat: lat1, lng: long1 },
map,
icon: image,
```

});
}

This code is thrwoing me this error in the developers console
"**InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number**"

The complete JS Code is as follows,

```
<script>
var lat1;
var long1;
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#exampleModallocation').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
// get information to update quickly to modal view as loading begins
var opener=e.relatedTarget;//this holds the element who called the modal 
//we get details from attributes
lat1=$(opener).attr('latitude');
long1=$(opener).attr('longgitu');
//set what we got to our form
$('#profileForm').find('[name="latitude"]').val(parseFloat(lat1));
$('#profileForm').find('[name="longgitu"]').val(parseFloat(long1));
console.log(lat1);
initMap(lat1, long1);
});

});

function initMap(lat1, long1) {
const myLatLng = { lat: lat1, lng: long1 };
const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
zoom: 4,
center: { lat: 6.927079, lng: 79.861244 },
});
const image =
"https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png";
const beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: { lat: lat1, lng: long1 },
map,
icon: image,
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: It seems to be complaining that `lat1` is not a number. Have you tried logging its value in the console to check?

Comment: @El_Vanja Yes i have tried logging the value to the console and the lat and long values are shown in the console without any issues. But when i assign the same var to the coordinates it throws errors in the console

Comment: [This question with the same error in the title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585055/how-to-fix-uncaught-invalidvalueerror-setposition-not-a-latlng-or-latlnglitera) might provide some insight.

Comment: Great that link has the answer, adding the answer which was taken from that link as an answer below

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved with this block of code for this qustion.

```
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 16,
        center: { lat: parseFloat(lat), lng: parseFloat(lng) },
        mapTypeId: 'terrain', 
        disableDefaultUI: true
 });
```

The newly updated working code is

```
function initMap(lat1, long1) {
  const myLatLng = { lat: lat1, lng: long1 };
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: { lat: 6.927079, lng: 79.861244 },
  });
  const 
 image= 
 "Image URL";
  const beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: { lat: parseFloat(lat1), lng: parseFloat(long1) },
    map,
    icon: image,
  });
 }
```

Link to article with the original answer
[Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585055/how-to-fix-uncaught-invalidvalueerror-setposition-not-a-latlng-or-latlnglitera)