# Google Maps InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number in vue.js

Tags: google-maps

I'm using the GMapMap and GMapMarker components to display a map with markers.
I've verified that these values are Proxy objects, and I'm extracting the lat and lng properties.

I get this error when in Vue.js here is the code snippet

```
<GMapMap :zoom="14" :center="location.current.geometry" ref="gMap"
                            style="width:100%; height: 256px;">
                            <GMapMarker :position="location.current.geometry" :icon="currentIcon" />
                            <GMapMarker :position="trip.driver_location" :icon="driverIcon" />
                        </GMapMap>
```

```
const gMap = ref(null)

const handleConfirmTrip = () => {
    // Check if location.current.geometry has valid lat and lng values

        http()
            .post('/api/trip', {
                origin: location.current.geometry,
                destination: location.destination.geometry,
                destination_name: location.destination.name
            })
            .then((response) => {
                trip.$patch(response.data);
                router.push({
                    name: 'trip'
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
};

onMounted(async () => {
    // does the user have a location set?
    if (location.destination.name === '') {
        router.push({
            name: 'location'
        })
    }

    // lets get the users current location
    await location.updateCurrentLocation()

    // draw a path on the map
    gMap.value.$mapPromise.then((mapObject) => {

        let currentPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(location.current.geometry),
            destinationPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(location.destination.geometry),
            directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                map: mapObject
            })

        directionsService.route({
            origin: currentPoint,
            destination: destinationPoint,
            avoidTolls: false,
            avoidHighways: false,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        }, (res, status) => {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(res)
            } else {
                console.error(status)
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Please how do i get this fixed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix Uncaught InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585055/how-to-fix-uncaught-invalidvalueerror-setposition-not-a-latlng-or-latlnglitera)