# using if statements with input values jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have a short script that calculates a number by multiplying `input` values. That script works fine but now I want to add if statements. For example:

HTML:

```
<label>Width</label><input type="text" id="width" />
<br>
<label>Length</label><input type="text" id="length" />
<br>
<label>Total</label><input type="text" id="total"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
var w = $('#width').val();
var l = $('#length').val();
var total1 = 2;
var total2 = 3;    
if((w * l) > 5){
    total = total1 * (w + l);
    parseInt($('#total').val('total'));
}
if((w * l) < 5){
    totalnew = total2 * (w + l);
    parseInt($('#total').val(totalnew));
}
```

So if `(#width x #length) > 5`, the value of `(#width x #length)` would be multiplied by a certain number, in this case "2".

[Tried to figure it out on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sKyKv/).

Here is the code that works without the if statements: http://jsfiddle.net/e45SJ/

**How can I implement what I am looking to achieve with the if statements with the code I already have?**

**EDIT: How can I add more than one if statement? I tried this:** http://jsfiddle.net/m2LxV/2/

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this: `parseInt($('#total').val('total'));` as it makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple problems

1. You need to do the calculation in a change handler which will get called when length/height is changed
2. You are doing a string concatenation when you do `w + l` because both `w` and `l` are string values
3. `l + w` is 5 then none of your `if` conditions are satisfied.
4. `parseInt($('#total').val('total'))` just assigns the value `total` to the element and the `parseInt` does not make any sense

You need to use a change handler

```
jQuery(function () {
    var total1 = 2;
    var total2 = 3;

    $('#width, #length').change(function () {
        var w = +$('#width').val();
        var l = +$('#length').val();
        var total;
        if ((w * l) > 5) {
            total = total1 * (w + l);
        } else {
            total = total2 * (w + l);
        }
        $('#total').val(total);
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m2LxV/)

Comment: Does the + cast it as an integer?

Comment: @Bic yes... instead of `parseInt()`

Comment: Why use + instead of parseInt?

Comment: @cgatian there is not much difference between those 2 if the expected values are valid see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090518/string-to-int-use-parseint-or-number , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106681/parseint-vs-unary-plus-when-to-use-which and http://jsperf.com/parseint-vs-unary-operator - for me it is less typing here

Comment: But it adds more ambiguity to the code. IMO typing a few extra characters is worth the readability boost.  I've used the binary addition operator "|" to perform what Math.floor() does, and always leave comments. FYI the pipe performs better than Math.floor()

Comment: How can I add more than one if statement to the code? I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/m2LxV/2/

Answer (score 2):

Since the question asked to use your code to make the modification thats what I did. Not much has changed here and I commented any parts that might seem difficult.

```
function calculate()
{
    //Parse the string value into an integer
    var w = parseInt($('#width').val());
    var l = parseInt($('#length').val());
    var total1 = 2;
    var total2 = 3;

    //Perform IF
    //suggestion to use an If {} Else
    if((w * l) > 5)
    {
        //Set an internal value of total
        var total = total1 * (w + l);
        //Update the label's value to total
        $('#total').val(total);
    }
    if((w * l) < 5)
    {
        //Same logic as above
        var total = total2 * (w + l);
        $('#total').val(total);
    }
}

//Simple button event for testing
$('button').click(function()
                  {
                    calculate();
                  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LLu5s/

Some things to keep in mind

- This is a great case to use an IF ELSE logic block
- $('#total').val('total') translates to > Select the input element and set its value the string string value of "total"
- [parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) will convert the string value to integer. So even though you selected the value from width and length its of type string. so performing (w + l) will actually result in combining the two strings together, not adding numbers.

Comment: I want to implement more than one if statement without an else. How would I go about doing that? Also, how can I do it without the calculate button? I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/m2LxV/2/

Comment: use an IF{} ELSE IF{} ELSE IF{} Or perhaps a switch statement.  http://jsfiddle.net/re6cg/