# What is wrong with that select options?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just trying to make a simple calculation with the values of selected options, however I get false result:
**pickUp 9 and returnTime 10, it gives no (which must be yea)**

but **pickUp time 11 and returnTime 14, it gives yea(which is right)** so it gives the right result with some specific numbers and with some numbers not..

Here is the (pickUp)select options:

```
<select id="ophalenUur" class="timePicker selectOption">
    <option value="-">Kies Tijd</option>
    <option value="8">08.00</option>
    <option value="8.5">08.30</option>
    <option value="9">09.00</option>
    <option value="9.5">09.30</option>
    <option value="10">10.00</option>
    <option value="10.5">10.30</option>
    <option value="11">11.00</option>
    <option value="11.5">11.30</option>
    <option value="12">12.00</option>
    <option value="12.5">12.30</option>
    <option value="13">13.00</option>
    <option value="13.5">13.30</option>
    <option value="14">14.00</option>
    <option value="14.5">14.30</option>
    <option value="15.">15.00</option>
    <option value="15.5">15.30</option>
    <option value="16">16.00</option>
    <option value="16.5">16.30</option>
    <option value="17">17.00</option>
    <option value="17.5">17.30</option>
    <option value="18">18.00</option>
    <option value="18.5">18.30</option>
    <option value="19">19.00</option>
    <option value="19.5">19.30</option>
    <option value="20">20.00</option>
</select>
```

and js:

```
var pickUp = 0;
var returnTime =0; 

$('#ophalenUur').change(function() {
    pickUp = $('#ophalenUur option:selected').val();
    $('.pickUp').text("PickUp: " + pickUp);
});

$('#inleverenUur').change(function() {
    returnTime = $('#inleverenUur option:selected').val();
    $('.returntime').text("return: " + returnTime);

    if(returnTime > pickUp){ alert("yea");
    } else { alert("no");  }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jLAaq/27/

What is wrong here? I am looking for hours and I can't see:/

Comment: You are comparing text, instead parse them in float and the check the condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you are doing a string comparison

```
var pickUp = 0;
var returnTime = 0;
var totalExtra = 0;

$('#ophalenUur').change(function () {
    //conver the value string to number by prfixing it with + or you can use parseFloat(this.value)
    pickUp = +this.value;
    $('.pickUp').text("PickUp: " + pickUp);
});

$('#inleverenUur').change(function () {
    returnTime = +this.value;
    $('.returntime').text("return: " + returnTime);

    if (returnTime > pickUp) {
        alert("yea");
    } else {
        alert("no");
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gqLj7/)

Comment: Just for clarification, why are you using `+this.value`and not `parseFloat(this.value)`?

Comment: @zahorak it is short by 9 characters :) .. also thanks for bringing parseFloat() in my comments I said parseInt()

Comment: Yes that's true I was just wondering if it's a nice style or a "dirty" hack

Comment: @user2045937 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106681/parseint-vs-unary-plus-when-to-use-which

Comment: @zahorak it is the unary plus operator... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106681/parseint-vs-unary-plus-when-to-use-which

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason could be returnTime and pickUp is string. so "9">"10".
Try to use parseFloat function to parse returnTime and pickUp.

Answer (score 1):

You were comparing the integer as string. You can use the `parseFloat` method

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/jLAaq/36/)**

**`CODE:`**

```
var pickUp = 0;
var returnTime =0; 
var totalExtra = 0;

$('#ophalenUur').change(function() {
pickUp = $('#ophalenUur option:selected').val();
    $('.pickUp').text("PickUp: " + pickUp);
});

$('#inleverenUur').change(function() {
returnTime = $('#inleverenUur option:selected').val();
    $('.returntime').text("return: " + returnTime);
 if(parseFloat(returnTime) > parseFloat(pickUp)){
       alert("yea");
   }else{
    alert("no");           
  }
});
```

Comment: i would rather use parseFloat(). Try to select 12.00 and 12.30. :)

Comment: yeah that right. It did not click to me at that time.. I changed my answer. thanks anywayz