# jquery sum of multiple input fields if same class in one input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Hello I need to sum the values of same class input in one input with class name total.

```
<input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
<input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
<input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
<input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
<input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
<input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />

<input type="text" class="total" value="" />
```

Possible?

[A working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5gsBV/)

```
$(document).on("change", "qty1", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $("input[class *= 'qty1']").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".total").val(sum);
});
```

Comment: +1 for asking ***Possible?***

Comment: So, this means its not possible? What if i change classes to ID?

Comment: So, this existing possible code you posted is not working? or what??

Comment: It means it's fairly trifle.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You pretty much had it, just needed to adjust your JQuery a little bit for the appropriate selectors

updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5gsBV/7/

```
$(document).on("change", ".qty1", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".qty1").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".total").val(sum);
});
```

Comment: @Andrei not a problem! Anytime you want to access classes or id's in JQuery you have to be sure you include the `. or #` ie `.class` or `#id`

Comment: thanks again, one more question http://jsfiddle.net/5gsBV/9/ how can I change "CHANGE" event on other so that it will sum the values even after page refresh?

Comment: @Andrei I don't believe the value's will be saved in the text field on the page refresh. But this should take care of anytime the `qty` field is changed.

Comment: Excellent Answer, the $("document").on(.....) also works to catch dynamically added HTML, which was my case.

Comment: Thank you adjit you can also solve my problem in one my project in early morning.

Comment: @bhavinthummar absolutely! Have you posted a question?

Comment: no @Adjit i have searched in google stakoverflow and i found your answer first and then my problem is solved.

Comment: @bhavinthummar ok good! If you have any questions just let me know

Comment: Can someone please explain why do we use "`+`" just before  `$(this).val();` in the function?

Comment: Ok I got it, it is a [unary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17106702/8407719) operator

Comment: very useful. it worked for me on 2023

Answer (score 6):

I suggest this solution:

**html**

```
<input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" />

    <input type="text" class="total" value="" />

<div id="result"></div>
```

**js**

```
$(".qty1").on("blur", function(){
    var sum=0;
    $(".qty1").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() !== "")
          sum += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);   
    });

    $("#result").html(sum);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gsBV/6/)

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is here:

```
$("#destination").val(sum);
```

change it to:

```
$(".total").val(sum);
```

---

And instead of `change` event i suggest you to use `keyup` instead.

```
$(document).on("keyup"
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).on("keyup", ".qty1", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".qty1").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".total").val(sum);
});
```

Comment: Whenever suggesting an answer, consider commenting your code for better clarity.

Answer (score 1):

We can use following own function

```
 (function( $ ){
   $.fn.sum=function () {
    var sum=0;
        $(this).each(function(index, element){
            sum += parseFloat($(element).val());
        });
    return sum;
    }; 
})( jQuery );
//Call $('.abcd').sum();
```

http://www.gleegrid.com/code-snippet/javascript/jquery-sum-input-values-by-class/?filter=bygroup&group=JQuery

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.qty1').each(function(){
  sum += parseFloat(this.value);
   });
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: While the code might be easy to understand for people with experience, beginners might need an explanation. Please add an explanation what your code does and how it solves OPs question.

Answer (score 1):

This will work with pure js

```html
<input type="text" value=" " class="percent-input"> <br>
<input type="text" value=" " class="percent-input"> <br>
<input type="text" value=" " class="percent-input"> <br>
<p>Total Value :<span id="total">100%</span></p>
<p>Left Value :<span id="left">0.00%</span></p>
```

```js
    var percenInput = document.querySelectorAll('.percent-input');
    for (let i = 0; i < percenInput.length; i++) {
        percenInput[i].addEventListener('keyup', getPercentVal)
    }

    function getPercentVal() {
        var total = 0;
        var allPercentVal = document.querySelectorAll('.percent-input');
        for (var i = 0; i < allPercentVal.length; i++) {
            if (allPercentVal[i].value > 0) {
                var ele = allPercentVal[i];
                total += parseFloat(ele.value);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total.toFixed(2) + '%';
        document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = (100 - total).toFixed(2) + '%';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it:

```
$(document).on("change", ".qty1", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".qty1").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".total").val(sum);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DUKL6/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/DUKL6/)

Comment: Adjit was faster :P please delete.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with all of the above answers is that they fail if you enter something other than a number.  If you want something that is more friendly to users, you should do some validation, perhaps even give some feedback when a value other than a number is entered.

```
$('body').on('change', '.qty1', function() {
    var total=0;
    $(".qty1").each(function(){
        quantity = parseInt($(this).val());
        if (!isNaN(quantity)) {
            total += quantity;
        }
    });
    $('.total').val('Total: '+total);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="price" placeholder="enter number one" />
<input type="text" class="price" placeholder="enter number two" />
<input type="text" class="price" placeholder="enter number three" />
<input type="text" class="price" placeholder="enter number four" />
<input type="text" id="total">
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(document).on("keyup", ".price", function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $(".price").each(function(){
            sum += +$(this).val();
        });
        $('#total').val(sum);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.