# Subtracting Date and Time from dynamically created datepicker fields

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have 3 dynamically created fields via clone() in jQuery and wish to subtract hours from an overall number of available hours. To help me explain, consider this image:

[image]

The first date is set dynamically (but can be changed). On the top right we have the total available hours. What I need is to calculate the hours set in the fields bellow (all created dynamically, more can be added or eliminated) and subtract from the available hours. I also need to consider that each time period does not overlap the last. Eg, When setting the next date, it can not be equal to the one above as the time interval match.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<table id="days" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Dia</th><th>Hora Início</th><th>Hora Término</th><th></th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr id="days0" class="hidden" data-id="0" ><td data-name="day"><input type="text" name="day0" class="input-block-level datepicker-days"> </td><td data-name="start"><input type="time" name="start0"></td><td data-name="end"><input type="time" name="end0"></td><td data-name="del"><button type="button" name="del0" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger row-remove"><icon class="fa fa-remove"></icon></button></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" id="add_row"><i class="icon fa fa-plus"></i></button>
```

And my JQuery so far:

```
$("#add_row").on("click", function() {
    var newid = 0;
    $.each($("#days tr"), function() {
        if (parseInt($(this).data("id")) > newid) {
            newid = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
        }
    });
    newid++;

    var tr = $("<tr></tr>", {
        id: "days"+newid,
        "data-id": newid
    });

    $.each($("#days tbody tr:nth(0) td"), function() {
        var cur_td = $(this);
        var children = cur_td.children();
        console.log($(this).data("name"));
        // add new td and element if it has a nane
        if ($(this).data("name") != undefined) {
            var td = $("<td></td>", {
                "data-name": $(cur_td).data("name")
            });
            console.log(children);
            $.each(children, function(index, childElement){
             var c = $(childElement).clone();
            c.attr("name", $(cur_td).data("name") + newid);
                if(c.attr("type")=='text'){
                    c.attr("class", "datepicker-days");
                }

                if(c.attr("name")=='start'+newid){
                    c.attr("value", "09:00");
                }

                if(c.attr("name")=='end'+newid){
                    c.attr("value", "18:00");
                }
            c.appendTo($(td));
            });

            td.appendTo($(tr));
        } else {
            var td = $("<td></td>", {
                'text': $('#days tr').length
            }).appendTo($(tr));
        }
    });

    // add the new row
    $(tr).appendTo($('#days'));

    if(newid==1){
        // If is first clone, set Date and remove datepicker class
        $("input[name=day1]").prop('readonly', true);
         $("input[name=day1]").val($("input[name=data_inicio]").val());

        $("input[name=day1]").removeClass("datepicker-days");
        $("input[name=start1]").val('09:00');
        $("input[name=end1]").val('18:00');
    }


    $(tr).find("td button.row-remove").on("click", function() {
         $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
```

For this stage forward I am quite lost.
I know the logic but don't know how to get there.
I am sorry if I haven't made myself clear. Thank you.

Comment: Did you tried something? I don't see any code in the post. Please, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I edited my question with my current code. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: Now you have more posibilities to receive help :) I will try to read your code and see how to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using other jquery Selectors?  For example, lets say you wanted to total hours, and to help with this you give all the hours boxes an "hours" class.  Now, with jquery, you could use the selector $('.hours') to select all hours class fields.  And then from there, you could sum them all.  With this approach, you can run an operation of each item in a class, without concern for how many might exist.

See solutions in [jquery sum of multiple input fields if same class in one input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126819/jquery-sum-of-multiple-input-fields-if-same-class-in-one-input)

This ability to grab things by class or in other more complex ways, and to work with a collection of objects is part of the beauty of jQuery.

So, then, you could on change of elements with this class, run a function that totals all the elements that match this class, and subtracts them from wherever such needs be done.

Comment: The issue is that I have to subtract End time from Start time and know how many hours in each day. Them sum them all and subtract that amount fro the total. And also I have to know that in real time so that I can make sure a user to creates a schedule with the total amount of hours equal to the training module.