# Why parseInt() doesn't convert "true" to number, while multiplying does?

Tags: javascript

I started from expression returning `true` (I choose `1==1`) and wrote it in console

```
cosole.log(1==1);
```

It logs `true`. Now I want to convert it to integer (`1`) and wrap it in `parseInt()`

```
console.log(parseInt(1==1));
```

It logs `NaN`. Looks like it is trying to convert `1==1` to string before it converts it to number. 
Then I'll simply multiply `1==1` by 1.

```
console.log((1==1)*1);
```

It logs `1`.

Why in first case it converts it converts `true` to string before converting it to integer (resulting `NaN`) while I want to convert it to string and in the second case it converts `true` directly to integer? I'd expect that `true*1` will be `NaN` too.

Comment: You may want to watch this video: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: parseInt makes the first param a string("true"), then attempts to convert the string to a number(why you get NaN).

Comment: `true * 1` is `1`, so effectively you're just doing `parseInt(1)`

Comment: practically the same as [parseInt vs unary plus - when to use which](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106681/parseint-vs-unary-plus-when-to-use-which)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`parseInt`, by virtue of being a “parse”r, should take a string and produce an integer, so it converts its argument to a string. `*`, because it’s multiplication, converts its arguments to numbers.

If you want to convert *anything* to an (32-bit) integer, `| 0` works; it’s a 32-bit bitwise integer operation, and can’t result in `NaN`, because that’s not a 32-bit integer.

Just to emphasize that `parseInt` is a wholly inappropriate way of casting anything but a string to an integer: what does this give you?

```
parseInt(5000000000000000000000000)
```

(For numbers that big, use `Math.round(x)`, or `Math.round(+x)` if you like to be explicit.)

Comment: `Number(true)` works as well

Comment: @hindmost: `Number` casts to numbers, like `*` and unary `+` – not integers.

Answer (score 5):

```
parseInt(bool) == NaN
parseInt(bool*1) == parseInt(int) == int
```

I believe Javascript makes `true = 1` and `false = 0` when you multiply it.

EDIT: to further this, `parseInt(bool*bool)` would also work