# Convert array of string javascript to array of integer javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, integer

I have an array,

```
var array = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
```

then I need to convert to

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

How can i convert?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Map it to the `Number` function:

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
array = array.map(Number);
array; // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 6):

> The [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.
>
> The unary **+** acts more like parseFloat since it also accepts decimals.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106681/parseint-vs-unary-plus-when-to-use-which)

Try this snippet:

```js
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
array = array.map(function(item) {
  return +item;
});
console.log(array);
```

Comment: good answer, but whats the point of the snippet which expands to nothing ?

Comment: @amdixon Just open the console (F12) of your browser ;)

Comment: point taken - it is just slightly faster than copy+pasting it into the console ;)

Comment: The unary plus converts things into a number, just like the unary minus converts it into a number and negates it.