# jQuery unwanted sum result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table head `<th>` that is set by default to `0`:

```
<th id="total_price" style="text-align:center">0</th>
```

Now when, I add a new sold item, the price should be added to the value of the this `<th>`. So, if the new one is 20000, the value should be `20000+0=20000` and not `200000`. And if I add another item, with price of 30 000 it would be now like `20000030 000`.

This is jquery script:

```
        var initial = $("#total_price").text();
        console.log(initial);
        var newPrice = initial + (res['price']);
        console.log(newPrice);
        $("#total_price").text(newPrice);
```

I tried this:

```
        var initial = $("#total_price").text();
        console.log(initial);
        var newPrice = initial + +(res['price']);
        console.log(newPrice);
        $("#total_price").text(newPrice);
```

But still the same.

[image]

Comment: You have to use `parseInt()`. `+` operator is used for addition and for concatenation of strings. Also, when you read text of DOM element, it is read as string and not number

Comment: You had a correct solution but forgot to put the `+` behind the `initial` since that's a string too.  `+initial + +(res['price']);`

Comment: If you want decimals, you should probably do a parseFloat instead. Also, if you want something like "30 000" or "30,000" to be recognized as 30000, you will have to get rid of them first. Do something like `res['price'].replace(/[ ,]/g,'')`

Comment: Thanks all. I appreciate it. Now it is working with both solution given by a comment from @squint and the answer of Reddy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse the text (string) into a integer and then add it up. So do below for your calculations

```
 var newPrice = parseInt(initial,10) + parseInt(res['price'],10);
```

Or else `what you are trying would be a string concatenation and not a Sum`

You can get **[More info Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)**

Answer (score 1):

As I have already commented, when you read text from DOM elements, it is read as string and when you apply `+` operator to it, its is treated as concatenation and adddition.

Following is a simulation:

```js
(function(){
  var th = $("th");
  var result = "";
  
  result += "Direct addition: " + $(th[0]).text() + $(th[1]).text() + "<br/>";
  result += "Type: " + typeof($(th[0]).text()) + "<br/>";
  result += "Parse Int: " + (parseInt($(th[0]).text()) + parseInt($(th[1]).text())) + "<br/>";
  $("#result").html(result);
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>20000</th>
    <th>0</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Also do refer following post: [parseInt vs unary plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106681/parseint-vs-unary-plus-when-to-use-which)