# What does the + mean in '+curr' - angular 2

Tags: angular

consider myself a ng2 "guru" but this I have not seen before :0

[image]

what is +curr.... (plus)?

came from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2436&v=U-GQ8Nz8agY

regards

Sean

Comment: that's not ng2 it's just javascript. it's a shorthand for [parseInt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106681/parseint-vs-unary-plus-when-to-use-which)

Comment: got it, figured it has to be a shorthand ... TX!!!!