# Calculate the total in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I'm trying to write a code which calculate the total of an array length of 3.
Each 3 integers are from prompt.

Right now my code is like the following:

```
var num1 = prompt("First number");
var num2 = prompt("Second number");
var num3 = prompt("Third number");

var new_array = [num1, num2, num3]

function sum_three(new_array)
    {
        return new_array[0] + new_array[1] + new_array[2];
    }

document.write(sum_three(new_array));
```

However when I see the result it seems that this

```
return new_array[0] + new_array[1] + new_array[2];
```

part does not calculate, it just concatenate the numbers.
How do I make work?

Comment: Parse your numbers to an integer.

Comment: Okay I just added lines like
var num1_int = parseInt(num1);
var num2_int = parseInt(num2);
var num3_int = parseInt(num3);
and it worked. But do you know is there any other way which I can reduce the code? I think they're getting too long.

Comment: Use reduce for the summing, and Number() to get numbers out of your strings. `let res = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + Number(b), 0);`. Your whole code: `let res = new Array(3).fill().reduce((a,b) => a + Number(prompt("Enter number")), 0);
`

Answer (score 1):

Inputs entered by your keyboard are strings. If you use 'addition' `+` on strings, you concatenate them. You have to convert (parse) the numbers contained in your string to an actual javascript number.

One simple way of doing it is by adding a `+` in front of each string variable. It will try it best to 'interpret' your strings as numbers

```
return +new_array[0] + +new_array[1] + +new_array[2];
```

Actually, the correct technical term is 'coercion', thanks @NeilDocherty, more info here https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md)

Simple example exhibiting the behavior :

```js
console.log("3" + "5"); // outputs 35
console.log(+"3" + +"5"); // outputs 8
```

You can also use `parseInt`, as you already did.

There are differences between the two, see for example this post : [parseInt vs unary plus - when to use which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106681/parseint-vs-unary-plus-when-to-use-which)

In particular, parseInt will return `NaN` for an empty string whilst `+` will coerce it as `0` .

Comment: This is called coercion, you can read about it here https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md

Comment: Thanks! I just parseInted the strings and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

A more modern solution would be to use the [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method.

I find this more readable, but if you are going to support browsers older than IE9, then you will need to [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill) it in.

```js
var new_array = [prompt("First number"), prompt("Second number"), prompt("Third number")];

function array_sum(accumulator, currentValue) {
  return parseFloat(accumulator.toString()) + parseFloat(currentValue.toString());
}

function sum_three(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(array_sum);
}
document.write(sum_three(new_array));
```