# JS calculates perimeter and area of triangle wrong

Tags: javascript

This is my first JS script. Code is running but wrong answer (50 times to high for perimeter). Can someone help me?

```js
function calc() {
var side1 = document.getElementById("s1").value;
var side2 = document.getElementById("s2").value;
var side3 = document.getElementById("s3").value;
var perimeter = (side1 + side2 + side3);
var area =  Math.sqrt(perimeter/2*((perimeter/2-side1)*(perimeter/2-side2)*(perimeter/2-side3)));
document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = "area: " + area;
document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = "perimeter: " + perimeter;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Side 1:
  <input type="text" name="s1" id="s1" value=5><br>
  Side 2:
  <input type="text" name="s2" id="s2" value=6><br>
  Side 3:
  <input type="text" name="s3" id="s3" value=7>
</form>

<button onclick="calc()">Calculate area</button>

<p>test1</p>
<p id="answer1"></p>
<p id="answer2"></p>
```

i just started programming? Is HTML CSS & JS a good start?

Comment: `var perimeter = (side1 + side2 + side3);`   side1,side2 & side3 are all going to be strings.  so  "5" + "6" + "7" would equal   "567", I'm assuming that's not what you meant to to do, try using `parseInt` or `parseFloat` on the values.

Comment: Learn to debug `console.log(perimeter)`

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("s1").value` is a string, so `side1 + side2 + side3` is string concatenation, not sum. Later, when you divide `perimeter` by 2, it is converted to a number. You could convert each string to a number by adding `+` in front of it.

`+` is an [unary operator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6), which converts its operand into a number. Unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a number, because it does not perform any other operations on the number.

```js
function calc() {
    var side1 = +document.getElementById("s1").value;
    var side2 = +document.getElementById("s2").value;
    var side3 = +document.getElementById("s3").value;
    var perimeter = (side1 + side2 + side3);
    var area =  Math.sqrt(perimeter/2*((perimeter/2-side1)*(perimeter/2-side2)*(perimeter/2-side3)));
    document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = "area: " + area;
    document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = "perimeter: " + perimeter;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Side 1:
  <input type="text" name="s1" id="s1" value=5><br>
  Side 2:
  <input type="text" name="s2" id="s2" value=6><br>
  Side 3:
  <input type="text" name="s3" id="s3" value=7>
</form>

<button onclick="calc()">Calculate area</button>

<p>test1</p>
<p id="answer1"></p>
<p id="answer2"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `parseInt()` on your input values since they are passed as strings. *The 567 result you have for the perimeter is obviously string concatenation*

Also please do have a look in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106681/parseint-vs-unary-plus-when-to-use-which) suggesting why to use `parseInt()` and [also this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106681/parseint-vs-unary-plus-when-to-use-which/17106702#17106702) having more test cases.

```js
function calc() {
var side1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("s1").value);
var side2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("s2").value);
var side3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("s3").value);
var perimeter = side1 + side2 + side3;
var area =  Math.sqrt(perimeter/2*((perimeter/2-side1)*(perimeter/2-side2)*(perimeter/2-side3)));
document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = "area: " + area;
document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = "perimeter: " + perimeter;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Side 1:
  <input type="text" name="s1" id="s1" value=5><br>
  Side 2:
  <input type="text" name="s2" id="s2" value=6><br>
  Side 3:
  <input type="text" name="s3" id="s3" value=7>
</form>

<button onclick="calc()">Calculate area</button>

<p>test1</p>
<p id="answer1"></p>
<p id="answer2"></p>
```