# javascript // (firstDecimal + +(secondDecimal));

Tags: javascript

in a solution for a hackerrank riddle i found the following code. the link to the riddle is https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/js10-data-types/problem

i have never seen anything before and in the internet was nothing to found about it. 
the code snippet is:

```
console.log(firstDecimal + +(secondDecimal));
```

what is this ++ sign?

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There is no `++` sign in the code you posted.

Comment: I see a `+` sign, a space and another `+`. They are definitely not the same thing as `++`.

Comment: The first `+` is the usual [addition operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition). The second `+` is the ["unary plus"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) operator (it's just a `+` sign in front of the value, it doesn't change the value but it forces it to be evaluated as a number, in case it's something else). `++` is the [increment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment)

Answer (score 1):

`+(secondDecimal)` is roughly equivalent to `Number(secondDecimal)`. It converts the value of `secondDecimal` to a number. So

```
firstDecimal + +(secondDecimal)
```

is like

```
firstDecimal + Number(secondDecimal)
```

If you don't do this, and `secondDecimal` contains a string,

```
firstDecimal + secondDecimal
```

will perform string concatenation rather than numeric addition.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this simple example, it is just a simple casting in js.

```js
var firstDecimal = '1',
  secondDecimal = '2';

console.log("Both strings:", firstDecimal + +(secondDecimal));

var fD = 1,
  sD = '2';

console.log("First numeric, second string:", fD + +(sD));

var fd = '1',
  sd = 2;

console.log("First string, second numeric:", fd + +(sd));
```

Read more about type conversation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp)

Comment: More specifically, this is called a [unary conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106681/parseint-vs-unary-plus-when-to-use-which)

Comment: Thanks, I don't know this! @SterlingArcher