# Is there any reason not to use the plus operator instead of Number() or parseInt() to return a number?

Tags: javascript

Basically, I'm trying to figure out what the difference is between these 3 statements? Is there any reason to use one instead of the others? Is the first one bad practice (it works but I never see it and doesn't seem to be taught anywhere)?

```
+'21';
Number('21');
parseInt('21');
```

Comment: Best answer in the duplicate links: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17106702/9867451

Comment: The first one is only bad practice when it comes to readability. If there is a lot of noise around what you're converting, it could be easy to miss, while `Number` stands out. But if you have something like `return +result` that should be fine. A unary plus is idiomatic but I personally prefer `Number` for conversions because it's easier to see and you can also use it in something like `["1", "2", "3"].map(Number)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know the first two are completely equivalent, and the choice between them is a matter of taste. (Personally I prefer the unary `+` because it's more concise, and well understood by most JS developers.)

`parseInt` is different because it reads a number value from the start of the string and ignores the rest when it reaches a non-numeric character. A common use is getting the underlying number from a CSS value like `"20px"`. Note that the other two methods would fail with a `NaN` in this case.

Answer (score 6):

parseInt parses the string up to the first non-digit number and returns what it found,

For example: `parseInt('123abc') // returns 123;`

`Number` tries to convert the entire string into a number if it can.

ForExample: `Number('123abc') // returns NaN`

`Unary plus operator` can also be used to convert a string into a number, but it is not very readable when it is being used with other expressions and operators

Internally, `+'21'` will work in the same way as `Number('21') * 1`