# How to get value of key from jsondata

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, lambda, amazon-sqs

```
{
"Records": [{
    "messageId": "20ea364e-3bc107b5c78c",
    "receiptHandle": "AQEB6DhNloFS4R66c=",
    "body": "1",
    "attributes": {
        "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
        "SentTimestamp": "15393506",
        "SenderId": "AROAJMTI6NE:errorLog",
        "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "15393511"
    },
    "messageAttributes": {},
    "md5OfBody": "c4ca75849b",
    "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
    "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-suth-1:83362:escalateErrorStandardQueue",
    "awsRegion": "ap-south-1"
}]
```

}

I want to get the value of key "body" and expected output should be : 1

Comment: Did you tried `data.Records[0].body`? where data is the name of the variable assigned to this `json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data={
"Records": [{
    "messageId": "20ea364e-3bc107b5c78c",
    "receiptHandle": "AQEB6DhNloFS4R66c=",
    "body": "1",
    "attributes": {
        "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
        "SentTimestamp": "15393506",
        "SenderId": "AROAJMTI6NE:errorLog",
        "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "15393511"
    },
    "messageAttributes": {},
    "md5OfBody": "c4ca75849b",
    "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
    "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-suth-1:83362:escalateErrorStandardQueue",
    "awsRegion": "ap-south-1"
}]
};
console.log(data.Records[0].body);
```

You can access the data by simply `data.Records[0].body`.

Answer (score 2):

If the name of the jsondata is `data`  (lets say):

```
data.Records[0].body
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
(data && data['Records'] && data['Records'][0] && data['Records'][0]['body']) || 1;
```

it will never give you any error and return key 'body' value if exist otherwise 1.

Answer (score 1):

If your records is an array, you could try to iterate your `Records` and get the value of body.

Also, if you're doing boolean conditionals, it is good practice to parse the value to an integer because data from a `JSON` will return string (naturally); in my example I parse it with the `+` [Unary Plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106681/parseint-vs-unary-plus-when-to-use-which/17106702#17106702) operator.

```js
var data = {
  "Records": [{
      "messageId": "20ea364e-3bc107b5c78c",
      "receiptHandle": "AQEB6DhNloFS4R66c=",
      "body": "1",
      "attributes": {
          "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
          "SentTimestamp": "15393506",
          "SenderId": "AROAJMTI6NE:errorLog",
          "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "15393511"
      },
      "messageAttributes": {},
      "md5OfBody": "c4ca75849b",
      "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-suth-1:83362:escalateErrorStandardQueue",
      "awsRegion": "ap-south-1"
  }]
};

for (record in data.Records)
{
  console.log('Normal JSON value:', typeof data.Records[record].body);
  console.log('Parsed JSON value:', typeof +data.Records[record].body);
  console.log('The Record body is:', +data.Records[record].body);
}
```