# How to convert string with comma to numbers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have some coordinates in a custom field:

```
45.4924038,9.2040718
```

And I am loading them into a map like this:

```
var mylatLg = "<?php echo get_post_meta($id, 'usp-custom-90', true); ?>";
var mylatLg = mylatLg.split(',');

console.log(mylatLg[0]);
console.log(mylatLg[1]);

var lat = parseInt(mylatLg[0]);
var lng = parseInt(mylatLg[1]);
```

The first console.log gives:

```
45.4924001
9.206260499999985
```

The second control.log says:

```
45
9
```

If I load the markers as per the following below, it gives me a wrong position (as it is 45,9)

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: {lat: parseInt(mylatLg[0]), lng: parseInt(mylatLg[1])},
```

If I load the markers as per the following below

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: {lat: mylatLg[0], lng: mylatLg[1]},
```

It gives

> InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in
>   property lat: not a number

How can I run `45.4924038,9.2040718` as I have in the custom field?

Comment: Did you try with `parseFloat()`?

Comment: what does it do? @LloydFrancis

Comment: @LloydFrancis I don't want to conver it to an integer, I want to keep the correct coords, maybe stringify?

Comment: So instead of parsing your values as a number, it parses them as floats. That means you can use decimal points. Just asking, do you have to parse them at all? Won't using it without parsing work? ( I am not familiar with the Maps JS API, just a question)

Comment: `parseFloat()` is same as `parseInt()`, only for floats. Float is a type of data that supports decimal points.

Comment: You can use `let [lat, lng] = '45.4924038,9.2040718'.split(',').map(parseFloat);`

Comment: @HassanImam nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `parseFloat` and not `parseInt`. This will parse the strings to floats.
Or just try to cast it using `Number`, e.g. `Number('9.206260499999985')` will produce the float 9.206260499999985.

Comment: That seems good to me. also about to post the same `Number()` one.

Answer (score 4):

Instead try with `+` unary operator which somewhat works like `parseFloat()`:

```
var lat = +mylatLg[0];
var lng = +mylatLg[1];
```

```js
console.log(+"45.4924001");
console.log(+"9.206260499999985");
```

Comment: perfect, it works. What does it do tho? I didn't know

Comment: FYI [parseint-vs-unary-plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106681/parseint-vs-unary-plus-when-to-use-which) will help you on understanding.