# Why Am I Getting An NaN Error For My JavaScript Code Arithmetic Equation

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

I am trying to create a wedding banquet table planner app for an assignment, but I am getting a NaN error for my "table" variable but not for my "guests" variable within my return statement. The picture is what I'm getting on my website, and below is script code. I am using HTML language with JavaScript. Thanks for any help!

```
function distribGuests() {

  // Read the table value inputed by the user
     var text = document.getElementById('tablesInputBox').value;

  // Convert what the user typed from text into a number.
     var t = (text);

  // Read the guests value inputed by the user
     var text = document.getElementById('guestsInputBox').value;

  // Convert what the user typed from text into a number.
     var g = (text);

  // Formula for variable "a", the rounded down value of guests
     var a = Math.floor (g / t);

  // Formula for variable "b", the rounded up value of guests
     var b = Math.round (g / t); 

  // Formula for variable "x", the end result for the first set of table distributions
     var x = (g - b * t) / (a - b);

  // Formula for variable "y", the end result for the second set of table distrubutions
     var y = (t - x); 

  // Use string concatenation to produce statement for end result of wedding table distribution
     var message = "There will be "+ x +" tables with "+ b +" guests and "+ y +" tables with "+ a +" guests";

  // Display the message in the div that has the outputDiv
     document.getElementById('outputMessage').innerHTML = message;
}
```

Comment: You may be failing to correctly parse strings into integers. The function you're looking for to assign `t` and `g` is most likely `parseInt`.

Comment: fyi, `(text)` doesn't convert what the user typed into a number, use `+text` intead

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses don't convert a string to a number.

```
  // Convert what the user typed from text into a number.
     var t = (text);
```

Should be:

```
  // Convert what the user typed from text into a number.
     var t = +text;
```

You can also use `parseInt(text)`, but `+text` is effectively the same for your use case (it's called type coercion).

(For an analysis of the differences between the two methods, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17106681/2714730))