# Join all array elements into one element

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a method that would join all array elements into one element?

For example:

```
var array = [1,2,3];
// array = [123];
```

Comment: so, 1,2,3 would become the number one hundred twenty three?

Comment: if you had `[1,2,3,4]` would it result in `[1234]` or `[123,4]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using **.join()**.

> The array.join() method is an inbuilt function in JavaScript which is
>   used to join the elements of an array into a string.The elements of
>   the string will be separated by a specified separator and its default
>   value is comma(, ).

Note that by passing the empty string to join you can get the concatenation of all elements of the array.

In other words **join('')** will also remove the extra commas.

The final result of this process is then converted to a number using parseInt, I think this is an easy solution to understand for beginners.

```js
// Expected result is an array like this
// var newArray = [123];
var array = [1,2,3];
var newArray = [parseInt(array.join(''))];
console.log(newArray);
```

**Bonus**
I see that many users here suggested the unary operator + instead of parseInt.

There is an interesting answer and discussion on the topic [here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106681/parseint-vs-unary-plus-when-to-use-which).

Comment: You can use `.join('')` then you will not need `.replace(/,/g,'')`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, @CodeManiac!

Correcting immediately.

Answer (score 4):

You could reduce the array.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3],
    result = array.reduce(([a], b) => [(a || 0) * 10 + b], []);

console.log(result);
```

A shorter one as proposed by T. J. Crowder in the comments.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3],
    result = [array.reduce((a, b) => a * 10 + b, 0)];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

With array.join you can can join all elements as string and then use Number or parseInt function to convert it as number.

```
const array = [1,2,3];
const result = [Number(array.join(''))];
// const result = [parseInt(array.join(''), 10)];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result=0;
var array = [1,2,3];
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    var a = Math.pow(10,array.length-i-1)
    result += array[i]*a
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `join` method

```js
var array = [1,2,3];
var joinedArray = array.join('')
while (array.length) {
    array.pop();
}
array.push(parseInt(joinedArray));
console.log(array);
```

Comment: that will return a string, not a number

Comment: and it wouldn't be an array either

Comment: A bit complicated in comparison to Pito's answer. You'd better use new array instead removing the original array's items one by one.

Comment: Thanks @C.Champagne
Performance of my snippet is also a bit better:
http://jsben.ch/UfT0M

Comment: @C.Champagne I thought you want in the same array, so I gave you a solution like that.  Thanks for pointing out. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Explanation:

`join('')` will concatenate all the elements in an array into a string.
`+` will convert it into a number.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3];
console.log([+array.join('')]);
```

Comment: I think they must be missing the `+` that converts it back into a number.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but there's no explanation. Just code.

Comment: yeah, I did ... but code only answers are also blah :p (I just deleted mine for the same reason)

Comment: This clearly answer the question as other answer, yes it's missing explanation, but we can guide new contributes to do so, instead of just downvoting and moving ahead

Comment: If the user adds some explanation, I'll gladly remove my downvote :p

Comment: Okay. Let me add it. I was trying to answer quickly may be.

Answer (score 0):

You also can do it like...

```
    var array = [1,2,3];
    var join="";
    array_size = array.length;
    for (let i=0 ; i<=array_size ; i++)
             join += array[i];
```

that will return a string not a number.
You can convert it to number using `join = Number(join);`

Answer (score -1):

You can join it like this

```
var array = [1,2,3];
var joined = array.join();
joined = joined.replace (/,/g, "");
console.log(joined);
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
let array = [1,2,3];
let number = Number.parseInt(array.join(''));
```

Comment: You need to parse it to number mate, join returns string