# How do I convert a string of numbers with commas in it to an integer and add them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion

I have an object called `bondFilms` with the following properties, for example `"title"`, `"year"`, and `"gross": "272,828,282"`.

I want to loop through each item and add the `gross` values to get the total `gross` amount.

```js
const bondFilms = [
{ "title" : "Skyfall", "year" : 2012, "actor" : "Daniel Craig", "gross" : "$1,108,561,008" },
{ "title" : "Thunderball", "year" : 1965, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$1,014,941,117" },
{ "title" : "Goldfinger", "year" : 1964, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$912,257,512" },
{ "title" : "Live and Let Die", "year" : 1973, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$825,110,761" },
{ "title" : "You Only Live Twice", "year" : 1967, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$756,544,419" },
{ "title" : "The Spy Who Loved Me", "year" : 1977, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$692,713,752" },
{ "title" : "Casino Royale", "year" : 2006, "actor" : "Daniel Craig", "gross" : "$669,789,482" },
{ "title" : "Moonraker", "year" : 1979, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$655,872,400" },
{ "title" : "Diamonds Are Forever", "year" : 1971, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$648,514,469" },
{ "title" : "Quantum of Solace", "year" : 2008, "actor" : "Daniel Craig", "gross" : "$622,246,378" },
{ "title" : "From Russia with Love", "year" : 1963, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$576,277,964" },
{ "title" : "Die Another Day", "year" : 2002, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$543,639,638" },
{ "title" : "Goldeneye", "year" : 1995, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$529,548,711" },
{ "title" : "On Her Majesty's Secret Service", "year" : 1969, "actor" : "George Lazenby", "gross" : "$505,899,782" },
{ "title" : "The World is Not Enough", "year" : 1999, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$491,617,153" },
{ "title" : "For Your Eyes Only", "year" : 1981, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$486,468,881" },
{ "title" : "Tomorrow Never Dies", "year" : 1997, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$478,946,402" },
{ "title" : "The Man with the Golden Gun", "year" : 1974, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$448,249,281" },
{ "title" : "Dr. No", "year" : 1962, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$440,759,072" },
{ "title" : "Octopussy", "year" : 1983, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$426,244,352" },
{ "title" : "The Living Daylights", "year" : 1987, "actor" : "Timothy Dalton", "gross" : "$381,088,866" },
{ "title" : "A View to a Kill", "year" : 1985, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$321,172,633" },
{ "title" : "License to Kill", "year" : 1989, "actor" : "Timothy Dalton", "gross" : "$285,157,191" }
];

let result = 0;
bondFilms.forEach((film)=>{
result = result + parseInt(film.gross.replace(",", ""))};
console.log(result);
```

However, for some reason I keep on getting `NaN`. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I included bond films @ggorlen

Comment: You need to remove (replace) the `$`

Comment: It will not work because gross is having $ sign so parseInt will not be able to convert and give you NaN.

Comment: so in this question i would need to replace both commas and $? how would i do that

Comment: The same way you replaced comma, replace $ also ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reproduction of the problem is:

```js
console.log(parseInt("$42"));
```

That is, we need to account for the `"$"`, because `parseInt` can't. We can do this by passing a regex to [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace): `/[$,]/g`, which matches any literal `"$"` or `","` character (we could also use something like `/\D/g`, being wary that we might accidentally chop leading negative signs). Note the `g` global flag.

Also, note that you're missing a closing `)` on your `filter` function.

```js
const bondFilms = [{ "title" : "Skyfall", "year" : 2012, "actor" : "Daniel Craig", "gross" : "$1,108,561,008" },{ "title" : "Thunderball", "year" : 1965, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$1,014,941,117" },{ "title" : "Goldfinger", "year" : 1964, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$912,257,512" },{ "title" : "Live and Let Die", "year" : 1973, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$825,110,761" },{ "title" : "You Only Live Twice", "year" : 1967, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$756,544,419" },{ "title" : "The Spy Who Loved Me", "year" : 1977, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$692,713,752" },{ "title" : "Casino Royale", "year" : 2006, "actor" : "Daniel Craig", "gross" : "$669,789,482" },{ "title" : "Moonraker", "year" : 1979, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$655,872,400" },{ "title" : "Diamonds Are Forever", "year" : 1971, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$648,514,469" },{ "title" : "Quantum of Solace", "year" : 2008, "actor" : "Daniel Craig", "gross" : "$622,246,378" },{ "title" : "From Russia with Love", "year" : 1963, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$576,277,964" },{ "title" : "Die Another Day", "year" : 2002, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$543,639,638" },{ "title" : "Goldeneye", "year" : 1995, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$529,548,711" },{ "title" : "On Her Majesty's Secret Service", "year" : 1969, "actor" : "George Lazenby", "gross" : "$505,899,782" },{ "title" : "The World is Not Enough", "year" : 1999, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$491,617,153" },{ "title" : "For Your Eyes Only", "year" : 1981, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$486,468,881" },{ "title" : "Tomorrow Never Dies", "year" : 1997, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$478,946,402" },{ "title" : "The Man with the Golden Gun", "year" : 1974, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$448,249,281" },{ "title" : "Dr. No", "year" : 1962, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$440,759,072" },{ "title" : "Octopussy", "year" : 1983, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$426,244,352" },{ "title" : "The Living Daylights", "year" : 1987, "actor" : "Timothy Dalton", "gross" : "$381,088,866" },{ "title" : "A View to a Kill", "year" : 1985, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$321,172,633" },{ "title" : "License to Kill", "year" : 1989, "actor" : "Timothy Dalton", "gross" : "$285,157,191" }];
let result = 0;
bondFilms.forEach((film) => {
  result = result + parseInt(film.gross.replace(/[$,]/g, ""))
});
console.log(result);
```

There are more succinct ways of achieving a reduction (transforming an array to a single value), for example [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), which accumulates a total using a callback function for each element in the array and an initial value for the accumulator. The unary `+` operator gives the same results as [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), performing a conversion without `parseInt` (results [can be different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17106702/6243352), but edge cases are unlikely here).

```js
const bondFilms = [{ "title" : "Skyfall", "year" : 2012, "actor" : "Daniel Craig", "gross" : "$1,108,561,008" },{ "title" : "Thunderball", "year" : 1965, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$1,014,941,117" },{ "title" : "Goldfinger", "year" : 1964, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$912,257,512" },{ "title" : "Live and Let Die", "year" : 1973, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$825,110,761" },{ "title" : "You Only Live Twice", "year" : 1967, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$756,544,419" },{ "title" : "The Spy Who Loved Me", "year" : 1977, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$692,713,752" },{ "title" : "Casino Royale", "year" : 2006, "actor" : "Daniel Craig", "gross" : "$669,789,482" },{ "title" : "Moonraker", "year" : 1979, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$655,872,400" },{ "title" : "Diamonds Are Forever", "year" : 1971, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$648,514,469" },{ "title" : "Quantum of Solace", "year" : 2008, "actor" : "Daniel Craig", "gross" : "$622,246,378" },{ "title" : "From Russia with Love", "year" : 1963, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$576,277,964" },{ "title" : "Die Another Day", "year" : 2002, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$543,639,638" },{ "title" : "Goldeneye", "year" : 1995, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$529,548,711" },{ "title" : "On Her Majesty's Secret Service", "year" : 1969, "actor" : "George Lazenby", "gross" : "$505,899,782" },{ "title" : "The World is Not Enough", "year" : 1999, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$491,617,153" },{ "title" : "For Your Eyes Only", "year" : 1981, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$486,468,881" },{ "title" : "Tomorrow Never Dies", "year" : 1997, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$478,946,402" },{ "title" : "The Man with the Golden Gun", "year" : 1974, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$448,249,281" },{ "title" : "Dr. No", "year" : 1962, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$440,759,072" },{ "title" : "Octopussy", "year" : 1983, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$426,244,352" },{ "title" : "The Living Daylights", "year" : 1987, "actor" : "Timothy Dalton", "gross" : "$381,088,866" },{ "title" : "A View to a Kill", "year" : 1985, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$321,172,633" },{ "title" : "License to Kill", "year" : 1989, "actor" : "Timothy Dalton", "gross" : "$285,157,191" }];

const result = bondFilms.reduce((a, e) => 
  a + +e.gross.replace(/[$,]/g, ""), 0)
;
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
let result = 0;
bondFilms.forEach((film)=>{
    result = result +  parseInt((film.gross.replace(/[$,]/g, "")});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: this gives the final answer to be 11.7 million

Comment: Yes, use a calculator on your computer, add them manually. It will match to the output of above code. In JS numbers are 53 based bits so it should work.

Comment: this is what the final answer should be 13821621224

Comment: I just updated my code, try this. There was missing parentheses.

Comment: Your error is that you're only replacing the first comma. Once `parseInt` gets to the second one, it stops parsing and returns what it has accumulated to that point.

Comment: ... `parseInt("123,456,789".replace(",", "")); // 123456`

Comment: Updated my code to use regular expression. I agree replace will only replace the first instance found. I kind of used the same code shared by the publisher only to outline to replace $. Thanks anyways..

Answer (score 0):

This is a good case for a `.reduce()` operation.

```js
const bondFilms = [
{ "title" : "Skyfall", "year" : 2012, "actor" : "Daniel Craig", "gross" : "$1,108,561,008" },
{ "title" : "Thunderball", "year" : 1965, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$1,014,941,117" },
{ "title" : "Goldfinger", "year" : 1964, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$912,257,512" },
{ "title" : "Live and Let Die", "year" : 1973, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$825,110,761" },
{ "title" : "You Only Live Twice", "year" : 1967, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$756,544,419" },
{ "title" : "The Spy Who Loved Me", "year" : 1977, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$692,713,752" },
{ "title" : "Casino Royale", "year" : 2006, "actor" : "Daniel Craig", "gross" : "$669,789,482" },
{ "title" : "Moonraker", "year" : 1979, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$655,872,400" },
{ "title" : "Diamonds Are Forever", "year" : 1971, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$648,514,469" },
{ "title" : "Quantum of Solace", "year" : 2008, "actor" : "Daniel Craig", "gross" : "$622,246,378" },
{ "title" : "From Russia with Love", "year" : 1963, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$576,277,964" },
{ "title" : "Die Another Day", "year" : 2002, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$543,639,638" },
{ "title" : "Goldeneye", "year" : 1995, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$529,548,711" },
{ "title" : "On Her Majesty's Secret Service", "year" : 1969, "actor" : "George Lazenby", "gross" : "$505,899,782" },
{ "title" : "The World is Not Enough", "year" : 1999, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$491,617,153" },
{ "title" : "For Your Eyes Only", "year" : 1981, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$486,468,881" },
{ "title" : "Tomorrow Never Dies", "year" : 1997, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$478,946,402" },
{ "title" : "The Man with the Golden Gun", "year" : 1974, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$448,249,281" },
{ "title" : "Dr. No", "year" : 1962, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$440,759,072" },
{ "title" : "Octopussy", "year" : 1983, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$426,244,352" },
{ "title" : "The Living Daylights", "year" : 1987, "actor" : "Timothy Dalton", "gross" : "$381,088,866" },
{ "title" : "A View to a Kill", "year" : 1985, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$321,172,633" },
{ "title" : "License to Kill", "year" : 1989, "actor" : "Timothy Dalton", "gross" : "$285,157,191" }
];

let result = bondFilms.reduce((acc, film) =>
  acc + parseFloat(film.gross.slice(1).replace(/,/g, "")), 0
);

console.log(result);
```

I used `.slice()` to skip over the dollar sign, since its position is known to be the first character.

Then a global regex removes the commas.

The result is then parsed into a float.

Comment: @ggorlen: I'd argue that if the format of the data changes, there are more serious issues to deal with.

Comment: Instead of using slice and getting rid of first character, you should use regular expression so even if the $ sign position is in the end, the code will still work, especially if the number is like “-42$”

Comment: @SagarAgrawal: That's overly defensive. It would be odd for variations in a format of structured data. I would only do that if I knew that was a possibility. We could just as easily suggest that the name of the property may be altered.

Answer (score 0):

*The most effective solution would be to map the object then make a match in the gross value, so that it detects numerical values in the string.*

Then use a reduce to make the final sum of the gross.

```
const bondFilms = [
    { "title" : "Skyfall", "year" : 2012, "actor" : "Daniel Craig", "gross" : "$1,108,561,008" },
    { "title" : "Thunderball", "year" : 1965, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$1,014,941,117" },
    { "title" : "Goldfinger", "year" : 1964, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$912,257,512" },
    { "title" : "Live and Let Die", "year" : 1973, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$825,110,761" },
    { "title" : "You Only Live Twice", "year" : 1967, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$756,544,419" },
    { "title" : "The Spy Who Loved Me", "year" : 1977, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$692,713,752" },
    { "title" : "Casino Royale", "year" : 2006, "actor" : "Daniel Craig", "gross" : "$669,789,482" },
    { "title" : "Moonraker", "year" : 1979, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$655,872,400" },
    { "title" : "Diamonds Are Forever", "year" : 1971, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$648,514,469" },
    { "title" : "Quantum of Solace", "year" : 2008, "actor" : "Daniel Craig", "gross" : "$622,246,378" },
    { "title" : "From Russia with Love", "year" : 1963, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$576,277,964" },
    { "title" : "Die Another Day", "year" : 2002, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$543,639,638" },
    { "title" : "Goldeneye", "year" : 1995, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$529,548,711" },
    { "title" : "On Her Majesty's Secret Service", "year" : 1969, "actor" : "George Lazenby", "gross" : "$505,899,782" },
    { "title" : "The World is Not Enough", "year" : 1999, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$491,617,153" },
    { "title" : "For Your Eyes Only", "year" : 1981, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$486,468,881" },
    { "title" : "Tomorrow Never Dies", "year" : 1997, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$478,946,402" },
    { "title" : "The Man with the Golden Gun", "year" : 1974, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$448,249,281" },
    { "title" : "Dr. No", "year" : 1962, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$440,759,072" },
    { "title" : "Octopussy", "year" : 1983, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$426,244,352" },
    { "title" : "The Living Daylights", "year" : 1987, "actor" : "Timothy Dalton", "gross" : "$381,088,866" },
    { "title" : "A View to a Kill", "year" : 1985, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$321,172,633" },
    { "title" : "License to Kill", "year" : 1989, "actor" : "Timothy Dalton", "gross" : "$285,157,191" }
]

const xs = bondFilms.map(x =>{
    return parseInt(x.gross.replace(',' , '').match(/\d+/g , 10))    
});

const total = xs.reduce((x , y) =>{
    return x + y;
});

console.log(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Sagar's answer to extract the numberic value, here's how you can do it in one line using Array.reduce:

```
const total = bondFilms.reduce( (prev, current) => (prev + parseInt(current.gross.replace(",", "").replace("$", ""))), 0);
```

Comment: Sagar's result is incorrect. Aside from that, putting everything on a single line makes code harder to read.

Comment: That is inline arrow function, with an intent to keep it simple. 

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, it seems to work.

```
var result = 0;
for(i=0; i<bondFilms.length; i++){ 
result = result +Number(bondFilms[i].gross.replace("$", "").replace(/,/g,'')) 
};
console.log(result);
```