# When to use + or Number() with string numbers?

Tags: javascript

I see there + operator is being used to convert a string number to number and same does the Number() function ,

So i am wondering there must be good reason for + operator before string number being used in most cases over Number()

Is there any performance enhancement with + operator?

appreciate your help guys

note : don't get confuse with concatenation of string , its **unary + oprator**

Comment: *Is there any performance enhancement* No. Essentially they both use `toNumber` function. So it all falls on personal choice. Most people use `+`(unary + operator) because its less typing. But few people like to have verbose code so its easy for you to read/understand. Hence `Number()`. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17106702/3783478

Comment: I suppose because `+` to type is fast.

Comment: Is there any performance enhancement with + operator? [Perhaps](http://jsben.ch/ZihEt). But I guess it depends on the exact runtime (I get opposite results with Chrome and Firefox) and it's probably negligible anyway.

Comment: Almost certainly completely negligible in 99% of real-world situations

Comment: Note that you'll get behavioural differences between `Number` objects and primitives, e.g. `new Number('4') !== 4`, but `4 === 4`…

Comment: I get the feeling OP was wondering about, eg, `Number(val)` vs `+val`, but not `new Number(val)`, which is weird and completely different. There are rarely differences between `Number` and `+`, it's mostly just a style choice

Comment: Number() is used for type casting and + is used to concatenate string & to add (if all operands are numbers)

Comment: @deceze I thought usage of `Numer` was `Number(4) === 4` and not `new Number`. Adding `new` will return an object. Like `new Boolean` etc.

Comment: @Aabir In this case OP is talking about the [*unary plus*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_2)!

Comment: @AabirHussain The `+` OP is thinking about is unary plus, not the addition operator

Comment: @Rajesh Both are possible, different uses. Just wanted to point out the difference when used with `new`, as it wasn't explicitly ruled out.

Comment: Sorry, I get my mistake from @Rajesh comment. thanks

Comment: yes , i get it , well i know new will create an object and that will never match and thank you for the resources