# What is this syntax isNaN(+str!)

Tags: javascript, typescript

Found it [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/4d03847cce58569c285da7cc4328ea0b0ebd45d1/packages/vuetify/src/util/helpers.ts#L177)

```
export function convertToUnit (str: string | number | null | undefined, unit = 'px'): string | undefined {
  if (str == null || str === '') {
    return undefined
  } else if (isNaN(+str!)) { // **** THIS LINE ****
    return String(str)
  } else {
    return `${Number(str)}${unit}`
  }
}
```

Comment: `+str` tries to convert a string (or anything, really) to a number and yields NaN if it could not convert. `isNaN` (is not a number, which checks for `NaN` type) checks if the conversion was successful.

Comment: @pascalpuetz, oh, makes sense, thank you, sir!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `+str!` combines the (JavaScript operator) [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) with the (TypeScript-exclusive operator) [non-null assertion operator](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/typescript/non-null-assertion-operator.html).

The `!` asserts that `str` is not null nor undefined before the `+` is done. But, due to the `str == null` test done above, the `str` *cannot* be `null` nor `undefined` at that point: the assertion is unnecessary.

So, it's equivalent to

```
+str
```

which casts `str` to a number. This numeric value is then passed to `isNaN`, which will return `true` if the value is `NaN`, and will otherwise return `false`.

Comment: It might also be worth noting that the `!` is a TypeScript feature. The usage of the `+` operator is standard JavaScript and not something specific to TypeScript.

Answer (score 2):

The `+`, or unary plus operator, converts an object (`str` in this case) to a number. It's similar to parseInt or parseFloat but not exactly the same. You can read more about it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106681/parseint-vs-unary-plus-when-to-use-which/17106702#17106702).

The `!` asserts that `str` isn't null, to suppress any warnings that the compiler would otherwise give. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42274019/8399253).

If `str` is not a number, then the `+` operation will return 'Not a Number', or `NaN`. `isNaN` will return true if `NaN` was returned, or false if `str` was a valid number.