# Calculate and concat strings based on array elements

Tags: javascript

Suppose a string like this `1.2-1.4`. What I want is to split this string at -, then multiply each of the parts by a factor, and finally return a string like `part1*factor-part2*factor`.

Ie. if the string is declared like this: `var range = '1.2-1.4';`, and factor is declared like this: `var factor = 10;`, I would like get a string like `12-14`.

So I did the following so far:

```
    var range = '1.2-1.4';
    var factor = '10';
    let complex = '';

    const parts = range.split("-");

    parts.forEach(function(element){
        // what is the shortest code that would concat the parts in the way I want?
    });
```

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) function together with [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) is probably the most straightforward.

```js
const range = '1.2-1.4';
const factor = '10';
const result = range.split('-').map(v => +v * +factor).join('-');

console.log(result); // 12-14
```

Comment: Note: The [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) converts its operand into a number. You may prefer [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number) for more verbose code. Refer to this [comparison of conversion methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17106702/13561410) for more ways.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the map() method to create a new array with the multiplied values and then use join() to concatenate them with the factor and the - separator.

```
var range = '1.2-1.4';
var factor = 10;
let complex = '';

const parts = range.split("-");

const multipliedParts = parts.map(part => parseFloat(part) * factor);

complex = multipliedParts.join(`-${factor}`);

console.log(complex);
```

This should output 12-14 for the given range and factor.

Comment: "This should output 12-14", but it doesn't.