# How to make a javascript window stay on top of all other windows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want my JavaScript window (Date-picker) to be on top of all the window (till I select the date or close it). Require Guidance

Comment: change z-index of your datepicker element to high compared to other

Answer (score 0):

If Date-picker window refers to an element within the html then this should do it.

CSS for date div

```
z-index: 20;
```

CSS for other div

```
z-index: 10;
```

Then you just show or hide the date div and it will always stay on top.

Do you need it to show but not on top, change the `z-index` to a lower value than the other div

If you don't have access to all the div's z-index settings, either check this post, [How can you figure out the highest z-index in your document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118198/how-can-you-figure-out-the-highest-z-index-in-your-document), to see how you can try find the highest or simply set your date picker to i.e. `z-index: 10000`.

**UPDATE**

And if you want a modal dialog popup div, this is a start for that

Demo:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLvcK

jQuery  (source: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal)

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
      height: 140,
      modal: true
    });
  });
  </script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
  <p>Adding the modal overlay screen makes the dialog look more prominent because it dims out the page content.</p>
</div>

<p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>
```

Comment: how can you specify the z-index to be 20 or 10 without code

Comment: You set it in the CSS in the first place. No need to alter that as the date picker very likely always need to be on top.

Comment: what will you do if the div have z-index of 1020 and div element of datepicker is 653 , then your code will not work

Comment: Well thats why I wrote that the other div need lower z-index. I do believe the Vishnu understand that based on his question.

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh I don't want it in CSS. I want it in          JavaScript . I am using window.open to open the new window. is there any other way to open & make it stay on top. Because I read somewhere we can use the pop div to do that .But not familiar in how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
newWindow = window.open();

document.addEventListener("click",function() {
  newWindow.focus();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't force a window to be on top of other windows via JS, nor should you.