# Dynamic url change <audio> for z-index img

Tags: javascript, image, carousel, html5-audio

I would like to change the url of a tag `<audio>` based on z-index of an image such as: 
If img z-index = 7 `<audio src = img.mp3> </audio>`

Images are in a carousel and the top image is always at z-index=7

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div id="coverflow" style="left: -391.19999999999993px;">
            <img src="img/rf_fip.png" style="z-index: 7; -webkit-transform: matrix(1, -0.2, 0, 1, 0, 0) scale(0.25); left: -284.7px;">      
            <img src="img/rf_culture.png" style="z-index: 8; -webkit-transform: matrix(1, -0.2, 0, 1, 0, 0) scale(0.25); left: -379.59999999999997px;">
            <img src="img/rf_info.png" style="z-index: 9; -webkit-transform: matrix(1, -0.2, 0, 1, 0, 0) scale(0.25); left: -474.49999999999994px;">
            <img src="img/rf_inter.png" style="z-index: 10; -webkit-transform: matrix(1, -0.2, 0, 1, 0, 0) scale(0.25); left: -569.4px;">
            <img src="img/rf_bleu.png" style="z-index: 11; -webkit-transform: matrix(1, -0.2, 0, 1, 0, 0) scale(0.25); left: -664.3px;">
            <img src="img/rf_musique.png" style="z-index: 12; -webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) scale(0.25); left: -664.3px;">
            <img src="img/rf_mouv.png" style="z-index: 11; -webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0.2, 0, 1, 0, 0) scale(0.25); left: -664.3px;">

        </div>
    </div>
```

I don't know if JS can be used or if Jquery is needed.

Comment: This post will give you a hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118198/how-can-you-figure-out-the-highest-z-index-in-your-document