# Find maximum z-index used in a site

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a widget to be used in other sites.

Is there any possible way to find the max z-index for the elements that are used in other sites via javascript?

Or how should I set my widget on top of all other elements using Z-index or other means.

Found that the max z-index value is 2147483647. Is it possible to override the max value?

Comment: 2147483647 is the max value of a 32 bit integer so no, you won't be able to override that.

Comment: Please don't use that value ... you can use a value like `1000` and make a note to the person who use the widget to handle that. If you set the max value you can mess up elements like modals - fancybox

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118198/how-can-you-figure-out-the-highest-z-index-in-your-document

Answer (score 0):

```
Browser             Max z-index value  When exceeded, value changes to:
Internet Explorer 6 2147483647  2147483647
Internet Explorer 7 2147483647  2147483647
Internet Explorer 8 2147483647  2147483647
Firefox 2           2147483647  element disappears
Firefox 3           2147483647  0
Safari 3            16777271    16777271
Safari 4            2147483647  2147483647
Chrome 29           2147483647  2147483647
Opera 9             2147483647  2147483647
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP already knows the max value is 2147483647.