# Display div on top of all elements

Tags: jquery, css

```
$('body').prepend('<div class="alert alert-warning newalert" style="width: 100%;height: 50px;position:relative;z-index: 999999999;"><strong>'+message+'</strong></div>');
```

I am appending a div to the body when a method is called.

I am able to bring the div on top of all elements,
but when the page is scrolled to the bottom and that method is called the alert div  cannot be seen since its prepend to the body.

Is there a way in css where i can show the alert as a popup over every element and not scroll to the top to see it.

Comment: `position: fixed` is what you need.

Comment: try to find your top z-index, will this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118198/how-can-you-figure-out-the-highest-z-index-in-your-document

Comment: @EdmundLee yes it worked

Comment: see jsfiddle in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position: fixed` is what you need. see this

https://jsfiddle.net/4hz53umm/