# jQuery UI dialog displayed behind WordPress main header/navigation menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, jquery-ui

I'm currently trying to create a `modal dialog` with `jQuery UI` on a `WordPress` page.

My issue is that the WordPress header/navigation menu (`div class:"main-header"`) is displayed above the modal overlay and the dialog itself.

I tried changing the `z-index` of the dialog **from 101 to 9999**, as well as adding `position: relative, z-index: 10;` to the `main-header` div's CSS, but to no avail.

Is there any way I can force the dialog and the modal overlay to be displayed above the menu?

Comment: Have you tried using position: fixed and z-index: 999999 on the dialog?

Comment: see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118198/how-can-you-figure-out-the-highest-z-index-in-your-document) might help you track the issue

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you inspect each of the elements, is `z-index` being over written anyplace?